# How can I capture the result of var_dump to a string?

Tags: php, string, var-dump

I'd like to capture the output of [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to a string.

The PHP documentation says;

> As with anything that outputs its result directly to the browser, the [output-control functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) can be used to capture the output of this function, and save it in a string (for example).

What would be an example of how that might work?

`print_r()` isn't a valid possibility, because it's not going to give me the information that I need.

Comment: I know it's passed some time but I've read this in the question: "is not going to give me the information that I need". So, it may be useful to add in the question what information you need.

Answer (score 656, accepted):

Use output buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();
var_dump($someVar);
$result = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Comment: Using output buffering will most likely have a negative effect on performance here. It also can get really messy if you need to look at multiple variables during the execution of a complex script.

Comment: @Inwdr I've only ever used var_dump as a convenience feature for debugging, and have certainly never left var_dump statements in production code. I imagine this is typical. In those circumstances, performance is unlikely to be at all relevant.

Comment: also remove the tags for readability (if you just want the string), using `strip_tags()`, this will simply return the type and value.

Comment: This is a good literal answer to the question, as you're 'captur[ing] the result of a var_dump to a string' exactly like what was asked. var_export() is a better answer in spirit, as it makes more sense generally.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Well, in extrict terms, the question is asking about the function named var_dump. We both know that var_export it is better, but as the user didn't know about it when asking we are in that point. As you can see, the answer below with var_export has much more upvotes now. This situation it is so tipycal in many other scenarios, because usually people don't know to ask better, or puts more importance on what they do than to what they need... but well, learning to create objects will not hurt you (others) so much, and you'll see the proper response below at the same price :-)

Comment: @AlbertHendriks I prefer var_dump. With Xdebug enabled you get a pretty data displaying.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. The `var_export` answer is long-winded and irrelevant, since it uses neither `var_dump` nor output capture, and `var_export`, like `print_r`, doesn't give types.

Comment: Even the PHP's `var_dump` documentations recommends capturing  the string with output controls.

Answer (score 973):

## Try [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export)

You may want to check out [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) — while it doesn't provide the same output as `var_dump` it does provide a second `$return` parameter which will cause it to return its output rather than print it:

```php
$debug = var_export($my_var, true);
```

### Why?

I prefer this one-liner to using `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean()`.  I also find that the output is a little easier to read, since it's just PHP code.

The difference between `var_dump` and `var_export` is that `var_export` returns a *"parsable string representation of a variable"* while `var_dump` simply dumps information about a variable.  What this means in practice is that `var_export` gives you valid PHP code (but may not give you quite as much information about the variable, especially if you're working with [resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)).

#### Demo:

```php
$demo = array(
    "bool" => false,
    "int" => 1,
    "float" => 3.14,
    "string" => "hello world",
    "array" => array(),
    "object" => new stdClass(),
    "resource" => tmpfile(),
    "null" => null,
);

// var_export -- nice, one-liner
$debug_export = var_export($demo, true);

// var_dump
ob_start();
var_dump($demo);
$debug_dump = ob_get_clean();

// print_r -- included for completeness, though not recommended
$debug_printr = print_r($demo, true);
```

### The difference in output:

#### var_export (`$debug_export` in above example):

```php
 array (
  'bool' => false,
  'int' => 1,
  'float' => 3.1400000000000001,
  'string' => 'hello world',
  'array' => 
  array (
  ),
  'object' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
  )),
  'resource' => NULL, // Note that this resource pointer is now NULL
  'null' => NULL,
)
```

#### var_dump (`$debug_dump` in above example):

```
 array(8) {
  ["bool"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["int"]=>
  int(1)
  ["float"]=>
  float(3.14)
  ["string"]=>
  string(11) "hello world"
  ["array"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["object"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (0) {
  }
  ["resource"]=>
  resource(4) of type (stream)
  ["null"]=>
  NULL
}
```

#### print_r (`$debug_printr` in above example):

```
Array
(
    [bool] => 
    [int] => 1
    [float] => 3.14
    [string] => hello world
    [array] => Array
        (
        )

    [object] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [resource] => Resource id #4
    [null] => 
)
```

### Caveat: `var_export` does not handle circular references

If you're trying to dump a variable with circular references, calling `var_export` will result in a PHP warning:

```php
 $circular = array();
 $circular['self'] =& $circular;
 var_export($circular);
```

Results in:

```
 Warning: var_export does not handle circular references in example.php on line 3
 array (
   'self' => 
   array (
     'self' => NULL,
   ),
 )
```

Both `var_dump` and `print_r`, on the other hand, will output the string `*RECURSION*` when encountering circular references.

Comment: Thanks! Used to use print_r, but this is way better for debugging. error_log(var_export($var, true));  All you need! :)

Comment: This is definitely a better answer than the accepted one.  I'm surprised it doesn't have more upvotes!  Could you elaborate on why it might not give all the information he's looking for?

Comment: @JMTyler var_export returns a *parsable* string—essentially PHP code—while var_dump provides a raw dump of the data.  So, for example, if you call var_dump on an integer with the value of 1, it would print `int(1)` while var_export just prints out `1`.

Comment: var_export lands on its belly if you use it with $GLOBALS while var_dump works.

Comment: won't work with variables containing references to itself.. var_export does not work like var_dump; like this, $v=[];$v[]=&$v;var_export($v,true);   ...

Comment: **Stop hyping** people. `var_export` isn't actually better for debugging because you couldn't do a browser search for `(int)` or (string)` and etc. It also mangles alot of information into a small space, just try: `var_export(''); var_export('\'');`. And most importantly, get ready for ***PHP Fatal error:**  [Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in C:\path\file.php on line 75*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5039431/632951#comment-5643967)

Comment: @Pacerier For me the first point is a benefit. I think it just comes down to preference. The circular reference issue is a good point, though.  I've added a comment about it to my response.

Comment: +1 @Pacerier this answer is worse, cause it substitutes the main question "how to catch result to string" by "how to dump variables other way"

Comment: This is definitely the worse answer. OP almost certainly asked about `var_dump` over `print_r` because `var_dump` gives type information, whereas `print_r` and `var_export` do not. This answer also muddies the waters by using type names as key names, unintentionally making it look (at least at first glance) as if `var_export` actually does give type information. IMO this is misleading, doesn't answer OP, and should have <0 votes.

Answer (score 89):

You could also do this:

```
$dump = print_r($variable, true);
```

Comment: I did specifically mention var_dump though :)

Comment: I personally prefer using `print_r` where I can, but unfortunately sometimes it doesn't provide enough information.  
For instance, since it casts to string where it can, both `false` and `null` show as an empty string.  In cases where I care about the difference between these, I would begrudgingly resort to `var_dump` or `var_export`.

Answer (score 22):

if you are using PHP>=7.0.0

```
function return_var_dump(...$args): string
{
    ob_start();
    try {
        var_dump(...$args);
        return ob_get_clean();
    } catch (\Throwable $ex) {
        // PHP8 ArgumentCountError for 0 arguments, probably..
        // in php<8 this was just a warning
        ob_end_clean();
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

or if you are using PHP >=5.3.0:

```
function return_var_dump(){
    ob_start();
    call_user_func_array('var_dump', func_get_args());
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

or if you are using PHP<5.3.0 (this function is actually compatible all the way back to PHP4)

```
function return_var_dump(){
    $args = func_get_args(); // For <5.3.0 support ...
    ob_start();
    call_user_func_array('var_dump', $args);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

(prior to 5.3.0 there was a bug with func_get_args if used directly as an argument for another function call, so you had to put it in a variable and use the variable, instead of using it directly as an argument..)

Comment: @MarkAmery Seems true. I just made it easy.

Comment: **PHP5.6+** `function vardump(...$args){if(count($args)){ob_start();var_dump(...$args);return ob_get_clean();}return '';}`

Comment: @a55 more like ```function vardump(...$args){if(count($args)){ob_start();var_dump(...$args);return ob_get_clean();}else{trigger_error("vardump() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given.",E_USER_ERROR);return "";}}``` - for PHP<8 when you give var_dump() 0 arguments, it triggers an error, so your vardump should do the same when there's 0 arguments. but if you are using PHP>=8 it will throw an ArgumentCountError exception, so your vardump() should also do the same in php>=8..

Answer (score 16):

Also `echo json_encode($dataobject);` might be helpful

Comment: In this case, output is very confusing and far away from debug purpose in my opinion.

Comment: Mark Biek didn't say anything about debugging, did he? Maybe he just needs object saved in the DB. In this case my offered method would work well. Thanks for the heads up anyways, Tomáš Zato.

Comment: Anyway, `json_encode` will not contain all the data `var_dump` does (as variable types for example). `json_encode` outputs the same information as `print_R`, inly in different format.

Comment: Ok, I will explain it **once more**. The OT stated that he needs output of `var_dump`. He also stated that `print_R` is provides insufficient information for his needs. There is no real difference in information that is provided by `json_encode` and `print_r` - only the data format is different. Given this, if `print_r` is insufficient, so is `json_encode`. Please don't complain about the downvote anymore. It obviously wasn't just random click, so deal with it.

Answer (score 15):

You may also try to use the [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function. Sometimes it is very useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: A word of warning - if the reason you want the output as a string is to `error_log` it, you should not use this solution, since serialize's output can contain null bytes and `error_log` [truncates strings containing null bytes](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64439).

Answer (score 13):

[From the PHP manual](http://php.net/var_dump):

> This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value.

So, here is the *real* return version of PHP's `var_dump()`, which actually accepts a variable-length argument list:

```
function var_dump_str()
{
    $argc = func_num_args();
    $argv = func_get_args();

    if ($argc > 0) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func_array('var_dump', $argv);
        $result = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $result;
    }

    return '';
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing the Real Answer to the actual question.  I'm reading this because I need var_dump, not var_export, print_r, serialize, json_encode, or a real debugger.  I know how to use those, too.  OP asked for var_dump, I need var_dump.  Thank you!

Comment: if you want to stay true to var_dump, you must trigger_error("Wrong parameter count for var_dump_str()");   when argc<=0 ; or better yet, have var_dump do it for you. :p

Comment: This adds pretty much nothing that wasn't already in the accepted answer. The `$argc` check here is unnecessary and arguably incorrect as pointed out by @hanshenrik, and once you take that away all you're really adding is the `call_user_func_array` and `func_get_args` calls.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have a look at a variable's contents during runtime, consider using a real debugger like XDebug. That way you don't need to mess up your source code, and you can use a debugger even while normal users visit your application. They won't notice.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the complete solution as a function:

```
function varDumpToString ($var)
{
    ob_start();
    var_dump($var);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: won't work with more than 1 variable...

var_dump("foo","bar")  => string(3) "foo" string(3) "bar" 

varDumpToString("foo","bar") => string(3) "foo"

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a bit off topic.

I was looking for a way to write this kind of information to the Docker log of my PHP-FPM container and came up with the snippet below. I'm sure this can be used by Docker PHP-FPM users.

```
fwrite(fopen('php://stdout', 'w'), var_export($object, true));
```

Comment: the handle is never closed tho, so this is a resource leak, which may be a problem in long-running daemon-style scripts. but try `file_put_contents('php://stdout',var_export($object, true),FILE_APPEND);`

Answer (score 1):

I really like `var_dump()`'s verbose output and wasn't satisfied with `var_export()`'s or `print_r()`'s output because it didn't give as much information (e.g. data type missing, length missing).

To write secure and predictable code, sometimes it's useful to differentiate between an empty string and a null. Or between a 1 and a true. Or between a null and a false. So I want my data type in the output.

Although helpful, I didn't find a clean and simple solution in the existing responses to convert the colored output of `var_dump()` to a human-readable output into a string without the html tags and including all the details from `var_dump()`.

Note that if you have a colored `var_dump()`, it means that you have Xdebug installed which overrides php's default `var_dump()` to add html colors.

For that reason, I created this slight variation giving exactly what I need:

```
function dbg_var_dump($var)
    {
        ob_start();
        var_dump($var);
        $result = ob_get_clean();
        return strip_tags(strtr($result, ['=&gt;' => '=>']));
    }
```

Returns the below nice string:

```
array (size=6)
  'functioncall' => string 'add-time-property' (length=17)
  'listingid' => string '57' (length=2)
  'weekday' => string '0' (length=1)
  'starttime' => string '00:00' (length=5)
  'endtime' => string '00:00' (length=5)
  'price' => string '' (length=0)
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: In 2021, for debugging applications error logging, this is the most useful answer IMO.

Answer (score -1):

To get around the print_r shortfall, (returns a 1/0 for true/false), here's a routine to convert true/false to "var_dump" type text before sending the variable to print_r:

```
$arr=['name'=>'Joe','male'=>true];
$arr1=array_map(function($v){
    if(is_bool($v)){
        $v='bool('.($v?'true':'false').')';
    }
    return $v;
}, $arr);
$out = print_r($arr1,true);
echo $out;
```

Answer (score -2):

From http://htmlexplorer.com/2015/01/assign-output-var_dump-print_r-php-variable.html:

> var_dump and print_r functions can only output directly to browser. So the output of these functions can only retrieved by using output control functions of php. Below method may be useful to save the output.
>
> ```
> function assignVarDumpValueToString($object) {
>     ob_start();
>     var_dump($object);
>     $result = ob_get_clean();
>     return $result;
> }
> ```

ob_get_clean() can only clear last data entered to internal buffer. So
ob_get_contents method will be useful if you have multiple entries.

From the same source as above:

> ```
> function varDumpToErrorLog( $var=null ){
>     ob_start();                    // start reading the internal buffer
>     var_dump( $var);          
>     $grabbed_information = ob_get_contents(); // assigning the internal buffer contents to variable
>     ob_end_clean();                // clearing the internal buffer.
>     error_log( $grabbed_information);        // saving the information to error_log
> }
> ```

Comment: Please properly indicate when you're quoting material from another source. Prior to the edit I'm about to make, the only part of this answer formatted as a quote is the part you *didn't* copy and paste from somebody's blog.

Answer (score -3):

**Long string**: Just use `echo($var);` instead of `dump($var);`.

**Object** or **Array**: `var_dump('<pre>'.json_encode($var).'</pre>);'`