# How to cast array elements to strings in PHP?

Tags: php, string, arrays, casting

If I have a array with objects:

```
$a = array($objA, $objB);
```

(each object has a `__toString()`-method)

How can I cast all array elements to string so that array `$a` contains no more objects but their string representation? Is there a one-liner or do I have to manually loop through the array?

Comment: have you looked at http://php.net/array_map ?

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682232/converting-array-values-to-string/42998701#42998701

Comment: @RohitSuthar : your linked answer creates an array out of a string. This question was about converting an array of objects to an array of their string representation.

Comment: In case you want to debug, you might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139474/how-can-i-capture-the-result-of-var-dump-to-a-string

Answer (score 228, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
$a = array_map('strval', $a);
// strval is a callback function
```

See PHP DOCS:

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

[strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php)

Comment: Can also be called like `return array_map(fn ($item) => strval($item), $items);` if you'd rather not reference the function 'strval' as a string.

Answer (score 3):

Alix Axel has the nicest answer. You can also apply anything to the array though with array_map like...

```
//All your objects to string.
$a = array_map(function($o){return (string)$o;}, $a);
//All your objects to string with exclamation marks!!!
$a = array_map(function($o){return (string)$o."!!!";}, $a);
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)?

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');

$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

Comment: No, because my array consists of objects, not strings. And the result should be an array and not an imploded string.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but something like this should do it?

```
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    $new_arr[$key]=$value->__toString();
}
$a=$new_arr;
```

Comment: read the question, it says "is there a one-liner or do I have to manually loop..." :)

Comment: Yes, and as I suggested in the comment to Alix's post I would have offered his solution had I have known about it.

Answer (score -2):

I can't test it right now, but can you check what happens when you [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/implode) such an array? The _toString *should* be invoked.

Comment: It does. Simple `implode($array)` will do.

Comment: @Gordon: It'll merge all the strings in one though, I think the OP wants to keep the `__toString()` generated strings in the corresponding array elements.

Comment: Right, I want the array to be still intact and only the elements in it casted to string.

Comment: @Alix Oh, I see. Yes. Then implode won't do.

Comment: `explode(',', implode(',' $array))` then, perhaps? Although, the proposed `array_map` would be more elegant, this approach *could* be done like this, couldn't it?

Comment: @nikc: Not if the generated `__toString()` contains `,`.

Answer (score -2):

```
$str1 = "pankaj";
$str2 = array("sam",'pankaj',"hello");
function Search($x ,$y){
    $search = $x;
    $arr = $y;
 foreach($y as $key => $value){
    $str = array_search($x, $y);
    if($str == $key){
    echo $key ."=>".$value;
    echo "<br>".gettype($value);
  }
 }
}
Search($str1 ,$str2);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Is there any reason why you can't do the following?

```
$a = array(
    (string) $objA,
    (string) $objB,
);
```

Comment: Yes, because actually I don't know how many elements there are in the array. The example above was just reduced to two elements to make it more clear.