# Convert array of MongoId objects to an array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

```
    [a] => Array (
      [0] => MongoId Object (
        [$id] => 506479dc9a5be1596b1bd97d
      ),
      [1] => MongoId Object (
        [$id] => 506479dc9a5be1596b1bd97d
      )
    )
```

I have an array like this one. I need to change the values to string, to change it to something like this:

```
array (
  0 => "506479dc9a5be1596b1bd97d",
  1 => "506479dc9a5be1596b1bd97d",
)
```

This is my solution, but it is expensive and I will be using this in a `for` loop.

```
$yut = implode(",", $a);
$arr = explode(",", $yut);
```

Are there any other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `array_map` to call [MongoId::__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoid.tostring.php) which would convert all Mongo Object in your array to string

```
$list = array_map(function($var){ return $var->__toString(); }, $yourArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array = array_map('strval', $array);
```

strval is php built in function that returns string value

like

```
function ($value){
   return (string)$value;
}
```