# count the elements in array except of specific element

Tags: php, arrays

For example i have an array like this `[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2.5,-1,-1,8.3]`
I want to count the element which are not `-1` like except of the `-1`. Is there any function in php to get this ? One approach which i think is

`Count the total array - count of the -1 in the array`.

how can we achieve this.

P.S : please provide me a comment why this question deserve negative vote.

Comment: Use `count()` with [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php); or use an [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count the -1 values

Comment: is there any direct approach ?

Comment: How direct do you want? count() with array_filter() is just two function calls that can be nested `$result = count(array_filter($myArray), function($value) { return $value != -1; });`.... sorry that PHP doesn't provide a `countExcludingValuesOfMinusOne()` function so that you can make it a single function call

Comment: yeah i understand but php provides like a in_array function so thats why. i think there is a function for that also

Comment: Yes, `in_array()` would tell you if a value of `-1` exists in the array.... it doesn't count them for you

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for answer

Comment: PHP typically provides several ways of doing anything, you could equally use `count(array_diff($data, [-1]));`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you sir! pardon my stupid questions i am very new to SO and php stuff .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@MarkBaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097089/count-the-elements-in-array-except-of-specific-element#comment81143900_47097089), PHP doesn't have a convenient function for every single problem, however, you *could* make one yourself like this:

```
$arr = [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2.5,-1,-1,8.3];

function countExcludingValuesOfNegativeOne ($arr) {
    return count($arr) - array_count_values(array_map('strval', $arr))['-1'];
}

echo countExcludingValuesOfNegativeOne($arr); // Outputs `2`.
```

It just counts the whole array, then subtracts the number of negative 1s in the array. Because PHP throws an error if any element in the array isn't a string <sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php#refsect1-function.array-count-values-errors)</sup> when using [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), I've just converted all elements of the array to a string using `array_map('strval', $arr)` <sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2131489/3088508)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop counter skipping for a specific number.

```
function skip_counter($array,$skip){
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ($value != $skip) $counter++;
    }
return $counter;
}
```

then you call `skip_counter($your_list, $number_to_be_skipped);`