# How to add double quote to array values php

Tags: php

I have an array like below format:

```
Array(
        [0] => 25/1
        [1] => 10/1
     );
```

But I want to convert the array so it would look like below format

```
Array(
            [0] => "25/1"
            [1] => "10/1"
         );
```

I have already tried lots of things about this issue but can't get the desire solution yet.

Anybody help please ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want these quotes in the view only?

Comment: It's already a string (there's no such primitive type as the one formatted in such way)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast array elements to strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131462/how-to-cast-array-elements-to-strings-in-php)

Comment: Just put the quotes in your view. The elements are already strings.

Comment: Yup do in the output or use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) if you really for some reason want the array values quoted https://3v4l.org/2PJur#v8.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to wrap array values in double quotes, here is a simple method with `array_map()`:

```
$current_array = array(red, green);
$new_array = array();

$new_array  = array_map(function($rec){
//concatenate record with "" 
$result = $rec= '"'.$rec.'"';
return $result;
},$current_array);

print_r($result);
```

Output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => "red" [1] => "green" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thx to the community. 25/1 are allready a string. If you echo 25/1 `echo 25/1;`you will get 25. PHP will convert it to an integer `echo getType(25/1)`. That means if you @Praful have these values you have already strings.

But in general [you can cast (Explicit cast) integer or other types with (string)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). or you can use the php function [strval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php)