# php var_dump() vs print_r()

Tags: php, arrays

What is the difference between `var_dump()` and `print_r()` in terms of spitting out an array as string?

Answer (score 397, accepted):

The `var_dump` function displays structured information about variables/expressions including its **type** and **value**. Arrays are explored recursively with values indented to show structure. It also shows which array values and object properties are references.

The `print_r()` displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans. array values will be presented in a format that shows **keys** and **elements**. Similar notation is used for objects.

**Example:**

```
$obj = (object) array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India');
```

`var_dump($obj)` will display below output in the screen.

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
 [0]=> string(12) "qualitypoint"
 [1]=> string(12) "technologies"
 [2]=> string(5) "India"
}
```

And, `print_r($obj)` will display below output in the screen.

```
stdClass Object ( 
 [0] => qualitypoint
 [1] => technologies
 [2] => India
)
```

**More Info**

- [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)
- [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: print_r(null) will return nothing where as var_dump(null) returns NULL which is useful when debugging

Comment: Two advantages of var_dump() is that the dumped information automatically is enclosed in a pre element. When using var_dump() you can see that each type has its own color. Enhancing readability.

Comment: @Julian only if xdebug is installed

Answer (score 60):

Generally,  `print_r( )` output is nicer, more concise and easier to read, aka more human-readable but cannot show data types.

With `print_r()` you can also store the output into a variable:

```
$output = print_r($array, true);
```

which `var_dump()` cannot do. Yet `var_dump()` can show data types.

Comment: var_dump() can be stored in a variable though it's a bit uglier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139474/how-can-i-capture-the-result-of-var-dump-to-a-string

Comment: you can also it's 'brother' [var_export()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) if you need saving

Answer (score 20):

`var_dump()` will show you the type of the thing as well as what's in it.

So you'll get => `(string)"var"` [Example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is here.

`print_r()` will just output the content.

Would output => `"var"` [Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is here.

Comment: I think the better example would be `var_dump(0.0);` which outputs `float(0)` vs `print_r(0.0);` which outputs `0` (hence leading to possible type confusion)...

Answer (score 14):

If you're asking when you should use what, I generally use `print_r()` for displaying values and `var_dump()` for when having issues with variable types.

Answer (score 9):

`var_dump` displays structured information about the object / variable. This includes *type* and values. Like `print_r` arrays are recursed through and indented.

`print_r` displays *human readable* information about the values with a format presenting keys and elements for arrays and objects.

The most important thing to notice is `var_dump` will output type as well as values while `print_r` does not.

Answer (score 7):

It's too simple. The **var_dump()** function displays structured information about variables/expressions including its type and value. Whereas The **print_r()** displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans.

**Example:** Say we have got the following array and we want to display its contents.

```
$arr = array ('xyz', false, true, 99, array('50'));
```

#### print_r() function - Displays human-readable output

```
Array
(
    [0] => xyz
    [1] =>
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 99
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
        )
)
```

#### var_dump() function - Displays values and types

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "xyz"
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
  [2]=>
  bool(true)
  [3]=>
  int(100)
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "50"
  }
}
```

For more details: https://stackhowto.com/how-to-display-php-variable-values-with-echo-print_r-and-var_dump/

Answer (score 6):

Significant differences between `var_dump` and `print_r`

both the functions **dumps information about the variable**, but `var_dump` multiple parameters which will be dumped, where as `print_r` can take two parameters out of which first parameter is the variable you want to dump and second is a boolean value.

`var_dump` can't return any value it can only dump/print the values where as print_r can return the variable information if we set second parameter of `print_r` to **true**. The returned value of `print_r` will be in **string** format.

The information printed by `print_r` is much more in readable format where as `var_dump` prints raw values.

`print_r` function can be used in many contexts where as `var_dump` can be used in debugging purposes mainly since it can't return value.

Comment: "var_dump can't return any value"? Yes it can. Kinda.
`ob_start(); var_dump($var); $dump=ob_get_clean();`

Answer (score 3):

I'd aditionally recommend putting the output of var_dump() or printr into a **pre** tag when outputting to a browser.

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($dataset);
print "</pre>";
```

Will give a more readable result.

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump($var)` shows in-depth details, by providing  additional details of

- data type of the value (including the descendant elements)
- number of elements in a variable
- length of the value

Answer (score 1):

With large arrays, print_r can show far more information than is useful. You can truncate it like this, showing the first 2000 characters or however many you need.

```
  echo "<pre>" . substr(print_r($dataset, 1), 0, 2000) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

**var_dump() :-**

1. This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.
2. This function display number of element in a variable.
3. This function display length of variable.
4. Can't return the value only print the value.
5. it is use for debugging purpose.

**Example :-**

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 2, array("a", "b", "c"));
var_dump($a);
?>
```

*output :-*

```
   array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

**print_r() :-**

1. Prints human-readable information about a variable.
2. Not display number of element in a variable as var_dump().
3. Not display length of variable in a variable as var_dump().
4. Return the value if we set second parameter to true in printf_r().

**Example :-**

```
<pre>
<?php
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
print_r ($a);
?>
</pre>
```

*Output:-*

```
<pre>
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
</pre>
```

Comment: "Can't return the value only print the value."
Yes it can. Kinda.
`ob_start(); var_dump($var); $dump=ob_get_clean();`

Answer (score 1):

We can pass multiple parameters with var_dump
like:

```
var_dump("array1",$array1,"array2",$array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For all who needs the var_dump() function for testing!

I've written my own test dump function, cause i didn't whant to do that ob_start ... stuff over and over again. The nice thing, it even get's the parameter names from source!

```
function test_dump (...$params)
{
    
    $file_test_dump = 'test_dump.log';

    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(0, 3);

    $caller_file        = $backtrace[0]['file']);  
    $caller_function    = $backtrace[1]['function'];
    $caller_line        = $backtrace[0]['line'];

    if (empty($params))
    {
        file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n" , FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, '!!!!!! ' . date ("[Y-m-d H:i:s:u]", time()) . " - FILE: {$caller_file} | FUNCTION: {$caller_function} | LINE: {$caller_line} !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! \n\n" , FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, "!!! No parameter given !!! \n\n" , FILE_APPEND);
        return;
    }
    
    

    // --- get source file ---
    $source_file = file($backtrace[0]['file']);
    
    // --- get line of source file and pre filter with regex ---
    preg_match ('~\(([^*]*)\)~', $source_file [intval($backtrace[0]['line']) - 1], $parameter_line);
    $parameter_line_filtered = str_replace(" ", "", $parameter_line [1]);

    // put parameter names into array
    $params_names = explode(',', $parameter_line_filtered);



    // --- OUTPUT   ----
    
    file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, "#######################################################################################################################################################################################################################\n" , FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, '### ' . date ("[Y-m-d H:i:s:u]", time()) . " - FILE: {$caller_file} | FUNCTION: {$caller_function} | LINE: {$caller_line} ### \n\n" , FILE_APPEND);
    
    
    $i = 0;
    
    foreach ($params as $param)
    {

        $i++;

        file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, "   --- Parameter " . $i . ': ' . $params_names[$i - 1] . " --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n", FILE_APPEND);

        if (    is_array($param)    ||
                is_object($param) ||
                is_bool($param) )
        {
            ob_start();
            var_dump($param);
            file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, ob_get_contents() . "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
            ob_end_clean();
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, $param . "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
        }


    }

    file_put_contents ($file_test_dump, "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

print_r() and var_dump() are Array debugging functions used in PHP for debugging purpose. print_r() function returns the array keys and its members as Array([key] = value) whereas var_dump() function returns array list with its array keys with data type and length as well e.g Array(array_length){[0] = string(1)'a'}.

Comment: They are not array debugging functions. Both accept mixed expression that can be array but it also be something else (simple type, object, etc)