# Why print_r() still exists?

Tags: php

```
print_r(array('name'=> 'bob', 'age' => 20, 'sex' => 'man'));
```

Then :

```
Array {
    [name] => bob,
    [age] => 20,
    [sex] => man }

var_dump(array('name' => 'bob', 'age' => 20));
```

will display:

```
array(2) {
    ['name'] => string(3) 'bob'
    ['age'] => int(20) }
```

`var_dump` is perfect to debug  and  much better than `print_r`. But why `print_r` still exists? or `print_r` has some advantage i don't know

Comment: Legacy code might be using it, so there is no harm to leave it in.

Comment: Yet another alternative to `print_r` and `var_dump` is `var_export`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r

Comment: Why your title still contains "PHP:", despite tagging?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A big difference between `print_r` and `var_dump` is that `print_r` takes an **optional second argument**, which allows you to the store the contents in a variable. For example:

```
$debug = print_r($someArray, true);
echo $debug;
```

(Note that this could also be achieved for `var_dump` using [output control functions](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), though)

Additionally, the **readability** of `print_r` is far better than that of `var_dump`:

**var_dump:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

**print_r:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

Answer (score 11):

If you output print_r between to `<pre>` tags then it gives you a much more readable output than var_dump. That is my main reason for using while debugging.

```
Array
(
    [name] => bob,
    [age] => 20,
    [sex] => man
)
```

Basically it gives you a formatted output that var_dump doesn't. Although it doesn't give you quite as detailed type information.

Comment: completely agree! print_r between pre tags is just beautiful :D

Comment: Yes, also why remove a function if possibly many software are depending on it, and will break? It's basic part of API design, you rarely remove something, and that's only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: beautiful, but mostly, with less clutter

Comment: It's obvious that you faked this output, since `print_r` outputs `(`/`)`, not `{`/`}`. :) [unless this changed in recent versions?]

Comment: Yes I mis-typed, its not a true output.
It's a big conspiracy.

Answer (score 2):

Can you suggest some reason to break hundreds of thousands of PHP scripts by removing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get as much data as you can use `var_dump()`, however i find that `print_r()` is more readable by humans.

Comment: Your second statement is incorrect: `var_dump` outputs public, protected *and* private properties.

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel : you are correct, i should refer to PHP5 more often :)