# using var_dump,value not returning in proper format

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($results as $result)
{
$getdata[] = $result->salt; 
$getdata[] = $result->password;
}

var_dump($getdata);
echo $sal->$getdata[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $pwd->$getdata[1];
```

Output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "f9e" [1]=> string(64) "61eed489ddfa309ab764hj876bfhfa5d18e3c3e695edc15" }
```

But i want the ouput like dis:

```
[0]=> "f9e" [1]=> "61eed489ddfa309ab764hj876bfhfa5d18e3c3e695edc15"
```

Comment: I will suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print_r($getdata)` insted of `var_dump($getdata)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $getdata[] = $result->salt; 
    $getdata[] = $result->password;
}

foreach ($getdata as $key => $value) {
    echo '[' . $key . '] => "' . $value . '" &nbsp;';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before printing the result, use

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

This will give you result in a neat understandable way

**FYI:**

The `var_dump` function displays structured information about variables/expressions including its type and value

The `print_r()` displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans. array values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements