# Codeigniter 2.x, ActiveRecord, var_dump(), what is the expected result?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to debug some problems I am having with viewing data from a database.  I am using codeigniter 2.x and active records.  Here is my code:

```
$data = $this->db->select('country_id', 'country')->from('mhcountry')->get()->result();

    var_dump($data);
    die;
```

Var_dump returns the following:

```
array(20) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "2" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "3" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#24 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "4" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#25 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "5" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#26 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "6" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#27 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "7" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#28 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "8" } [8]=> object(stdClass)#29 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(1) "9" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#30 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "10" } [10]=> object(stdClass)#31 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "11" } [11]=> object(stdClass)#32 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "12" } [12]=> object(stdClass)#33 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "13" } [13]=> object(stdClass)#34 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "14" } [14]=> object(stdClass)#35 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "15" } [15]=> object(stdClass)#36 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "16" } [16]=> object(stdClass)#37 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "17" } [17]=> object(stdClass)#38 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "18" } [18]=> object(stdClass)#39 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "19" } [19]=> object(stdClass)#40 (1) { ["country_id"]=> string(2) "20" } }
```

I have 20 countries entered from 1 to 20 BUT I do not see my country names in the var_dump.  It is just dumping the first field.  Is this normal or expected?

I tried the same thing on another table and it also just returns the first field.

Comment: You might want to read this about var dump


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r

Comment: You should try : `$this->db->select('country_id, country')` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pay attention to the documentation [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select), meanwhile you can try this :

```
$this->db->select(array('country_id', 'country'))
// OR
$this->db->select('country_id, country')
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and this question is not supposed to exist when the OPs read documentation (https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: Amazing!  I have been kicking myself for three days with this.  I totally overlooked the placing of the apostrophe.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this->db->select('country_id', 'country')->from('mhcountry')->get()->result();
```

This is wrong. it will get only country_id.
Use this

```
$data = $this->db->select('country_id , country')->from('mhcountry')->get()->result();
```