# what the difference in var_dump and print_r

Tags: php, mysqli

i simply use print_r and var_dump function for get the info of array.but i wonder they both giving a big difference.
print_r is showing that array  has 1 row whereas var_dump showing null on same array,
here the output
print_r showing this

```
   mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

whereas var_dump showing this on same array

```
object(mysqli_result)[4]
public 'current_field' => null
public 'field_count' => null
public 'lengths' => null
public 'num_rows' => null
public 'type' => null
```

i want to know what is the difference here... i thought both function same expect var_dump show data type also...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r?rq=1

Comment: hey buddy...there is difference in both questions....first read then rate

Comment: Can you show some code before the call to var_dump and print_r, as well as the calls?

Comment: $query="call findcty($this->ctycod)";
            $result=  mysqli_query($link, $query);
            var_dump($result);

Comment: your output is only possible if they are not the same object

Comment: I would say your title should be more specific, because you are not asking for "what the difference in var_dump and print_r" but to your specific case, "why print_r and var_dump showing different results". And for that as @Dagon said, it seems like both functions are not applied on same object.

Comment: yes...i do not applied same function of same object.. i applied one at  a time @Dagon

Comment: its not, its clearly not. there's nothing else to say