# Searching for PHP functions

Tags: php, function

Is there any function in PHP that just prints result of mysqli_fetch_array() as it is on the browser? I want to use it just for checking results of various test queries.
I want to print `r` in the code below

```
if($db){
    echo "connected";
}

$sql = "select student.Name, student.Branch, student.RollNo FROM student INNER JOIN students_placed ON student.StudentUserId = students_placed.StudentUserId";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$r = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

Comment: SO is not a search engine, Google is! (And PHP doesn't provide you functions like: `build_house()`, but it will give you: `tools()`)

Comment: really now??? did you even try searching this on google?

Comment: Try to search it on the internet instead of asking this question here.

Comment: Will remember that next time

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `print_r($r)` or `var_dump($r)`. They produce slightly different details about the variables you are displaying.

If you are displaying your code in a web browser, you can also display either one of the above commands a bit more nicely by wrapping it in `<pre>` tags as follows:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($r);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I wanted a function such that it displays the resulting table values along with the field names in a tabular format. But I guess there's no such function defined in the library. I'll have to define such a function for me. Thanks

Comment: You did not specify that in your question.

Comment: Yep it was my fault...sry for inconvenience.

Comment: It sounds like you may not want any further help, but I've updated my answer in case this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print_r`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

or

```
var_dump
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

For a clear understanding of difference between `var_dum` and `print_r`, refer this - 
[php var_dump() vs print_r()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r)