# Can't display specific content of an array PHP and Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm starting to getting along with PHP but I'm still learning, so I need some basic help.

I want to display only the value of the 'mini-description' in this array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => mini-description [value] => Suspendisse in tempus felis. [position] => 1 [is_visible] => 1 [is_variation] => 0 [is_taxonomy] => 0 ) )
```

and I'm trying to do this:

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$mini = get_post_meta( $postid, '_product_attributes', array( 'mini-description' => 'value' ));
echo $mini;
```

But the result is: Array

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean by _value of the 'mini-description' in this array:_

Comment: I want to display the content of the value field of the array -> Suspendisse in tempus felis.

Comment: Try using simply `echo $mini[0]['value']` and that's it

Comment: I've tried but does not work

Comment: @BorjaMuñoz from where you were getting this array? From which variable

Comment: it is a custom attribute from woocommerce that I've called 'mini-description', this array is the result of displaying the custom attributes

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo  $mini['mini-description']['value'];
```

or

```
echo  $mini['mini-description']->value;
```

Comment: Lol you've updated your answer and the array that OP have posted is pure array not an array of objects

Comment: haha yea...that's what I get for trying to help on the fly without actually testing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need value of 'mini-description' only, you can use following code:

```
$mini = get_post_meta( $postid, 'mini-description', true);
echo $mini;
```

You need to test this in your code. Let me know if works.

In Woocommerce, you can do something like this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $productId, 'mini-description');

foreach ( $terms as $term) {
      echo $term->value;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
print_r($mini[0]);
```

or

```
var_dump($mini[0]);
```

Edit use :

```
$toto['mini-description']['value'];
```

See the difference here : [php var_dump() vs print_r()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r)

Comment: If I use var_dump($mini); the result is: 
     array(1) { ["mini-description"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(16) "mini-description" ["value"]=> string(28) "Suspendisse in tempus felis." ["position"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_visible"]=> int(1) ["is_variation"]=> int(0) ["is_taxonomy"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: I only need the value, I only want to display: Suspendisse in tempus felis.

Comment: sorry, I'm new in stackoverflow... ;)

Comment: you're really close to the solution! with 

$mini['mini-description]['value']; 

the result is: string(28)"Suspendisse in tempus felis."

Comment: yes i didn't write the echo i was thinking you will replace youre $mini in the echo :)