# Defining an array of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have defined an array in php like this

```
<?php

$Category = array("Apparel","Grocery","Health","Gift","Footwear","Jewelry","Food & Bev");
$Shops = array("Giny & Jony","Big Bazaar","Health & Glow","Factory Outlet Store","Archies","Bata","100 Rs Shop","Silver Touch","Sri Devi Traders","Avatar","Steamzz");
$Type = array($Category,$Shops); 

echo $Type[0];


?>
```

When i am trying to print, it says "Err:Cannot convert array into string"
Is this way of declaring is correct?? If not,can you share your views.

Comment: What do you think `$Type[0]` contains?

Comment: use a for loop instead to print.. or var_dump()

Comment: you should always using print_r when your dealing with arrays

Comment: Var_dump gives similar if not better results http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to debug you variables, to see what they look like, a simple solution could be to `var_dump` em.

```
var_dump($Type[0]);
```

But you are not doing anything wrong, except you can't echo an `array` this is an legal print statement as an example.

```
echo $Type[0][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

It can't echo `$Type[0]` because it is an array. Array's can be printed using `print_r()`.

```
$Category = array("Apparel","Grocery","Health","Gift","Footwear","Jewelry","Food & Bev");
$Shops = array("Giny & Jony","Big Bazaar","Health & Glow","Factory Outlet Store","Archies","Bata","100 Rs Shop","Silver Touch","Sri Devi Traders","Avatar","Steamzz");
$Type = array($Category,$Shops); 

print_r($Type[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. @Thaillie

Answer (score 0):

try it and see result -

```
<?php

$Category = array("Apparel","Grocery","Health","Gift","Footwear","Jewelry","Food & Bev");
$Shops = array("Giny & Jony","Big Bazaar","Health & Glow","Factory Outlet Store","Archies","Bata","100 Rs Shop","Silver Touch","Sri Devi Traders","Avatar","Steamzz");
$Type = array($Category,$Shops); 

var_dump($Type);


?>
```