# How to implement a function with array

Tags: php

```
<?php
class FileOwners
{
    public static function groupByOwners($files)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

$files = array
(
    "Input.txt" => "Randy",
    "Code.py" => "Stan",
    "Output.txt" => "Randy"
);

var_dump(FileOwners::groupByOwners($files));
```

**Implement a groupByOwners function :**

- Accepts an associative array containing the file owner name for each file name.
- Returns an associative array containing an array of file names for each owner name, in any order.

  **For example**

Given the input:

```
["Input.txt" => "Randy", "Code.py" => "Stan", "Output.txt" => "Randy"]
```

groupByOwners returns:

```
["Randy" => ["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan" => ["Code.py"]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
class FileOwners
{
    public static function groupByOwners($files)
    {
        $result=array();
        foreach($files as $key=>$value)
        {
            $result[$value][]=$key;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$files = array
(
    "Input.txt" => "Randy",
    "Code.py" => "Stan",
    "Output.txt" => "Randy"
);
print_r(FileOwners::groupByOwners($files));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Randy] => Array
        (
            [0] => Input.txt
            [1] => Output.txt
        )

    [Stan] => Array
        (
            [0] => Code.py
        )

)
```

Comment: print_r() WILL NOT RETURN THE INTENDED RESULTS for the test. Printr() is human readable which is why the test uses var_dump https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one witch gonna work for sure:

```
 function groupByOwners(array $files) : array
 {
$result =array();
foreach($files as $key =>$elem){
  $result[$elem][]=$key;
 }
return $result;
    }
$files = array
(
"Input.txt" => "Randy",
"Code.py" => "Stan",
"Output.txt" => "Randy"
 );
  var_dump(groupByOwners($files));
```

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER WITH THE CORRECT RETURN: array(2) {
  ["Randy"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Input.txt"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Output.txt"
  }
  ["Stan"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Code.py"
  }
}

Answer (score -1):

```
$files = array("Input.txt" => "Randy", "Code.py" => "Stan","Output.txt" => "Randy");
$narr = array_fill_keys(array_keys(array_flip($files)), []);

foreach($files as $key => $value) array_push($narr[$value], $key);
return $narr;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The result is the same and I like the method but it is incorrect because it does not use a groupByOwners function. How will another developer find this class?