# Storing similar form inputs as an array

Tags: php

If I had

```
<input type="text" name="myArray[0]">
<input type="text" name="myArray[1]">
```

Could I access that field in the POST array like this?

```
$_POST['myArray[0]']
$_POST['myArray[1]']
```

(Background: I am trying to store multiple text inputs in an array in Wordpress, but I am not able to get it working)

Comment: I think it should be `$_POST['myArray][0]`. When doubt though use `print_r` it will show you what your `POST` has and all the indices.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST an array from an HTML form without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By html side, in the form, you can populate `myArray` and post it. Then by php side, you read POST as associative array.
So `myArray` is an element of the POST array. 
So, that's why you access an element of `myArray` by php side as follows:

```
$POST['myArray'][0];
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php there are examples with multidimensional arrays too.
You may find interesting this too: [POST an array from an HTML form without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript)

About debug: see differences between var_dump and print_r here [php var_dump() vs print_r()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r)