# Different result in array depending on the server?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

**EDIT:**
I added a repository in github. In "welcome" the result is printed.
https://github.com/Danven/borrar

LARAVEL 5.8

WITH VAR_DUMP (DIFFERENT!!!!)

```
{{ var_dump( $person->cars()->pluck('cars.id') )  }}
```

LOCAL MACHINE (PHP 7.3.7 ):

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#1215 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=> int(1)
    [1]=> int(2)
    [2]=> int(3)
    [3]=> int(4)
  }
}
```

PRODUCTION SERVER (PHP 7.2.12) :

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#1215 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    [1]=> string(1) "2"
    [2]=> string(1) "3"
    [3]=> string(1) "4"
  }
}
```

Comment: See this post it because of differences between var_dumb and print_r https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r

Answer (score 0):

Because in **PHP 7.3** Strings containing valid decimal integers, unless the number is preceded by a `+` sign, will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key `8` will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand `08` will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.

You can read that on: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I have tested it on another server with PHP 7.1.33 and PHP Version 7.2.26 with Production status:

`[1,2,3,4]` . The values are interpreted as integers