# How to echo an array in PHP?

Tags: php

If I have an array defined like this in PHP:

```js
$stocked = [];
array_push($stocked, "beer");
array_push($stocked, "chocolate");
```

How do I print out the array? I tried using echo, but it just gives "Array". What I want is for the output to be ["beer", "chocolate"].

Comment: use `print_r($stocked);` for array variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php var\_dump() vs print\_r()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the exact output you requested, you could encode the array as JSON, e.g.

```
echo json_encode($stocked);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$stocked = [];
array_push($stocked, "beer");
array_push($stocked, "chocolate");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($stocked);

echo '<br>';
echo $stocked[0].'<br>';
echo $stocked[1];
   
?>
```

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => beer
    [1] => chocolate
)

beer
chocolate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions:

```
var_dump();
print_r();  // You can use these with <pre> tags to get prettier output : echo "<pre>" . print_r($yourArray, true) . "</pre>";
dd(); // Note: this will halt the execution.
```