# Codeigniter 4 filters don't works

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

hi i want create my own authorization to study the new veri=sion of framework ...
this is my route :

```
$routes->add('/user/login', 'User::login',['filter'=>'usersFiltersNoAuth']);
$routes->add('/login', 'User::login',['filter'=>'usersFiltersNoAuth']);
$routes->add('/user/registration', 'User::registration',['filter'=>'usersFiltersNoAuth']);
$routes->add('/logout', 'User::logout');
$routes->add('/user/changeEmail', 'User::changeEmail',['filter'=>'usersFiltersAuth']);
$routes->add('/user/changePassword', 'User::changePassword',['filter'=>'usersFiltersAuth']);
```

And this is my 2 filter class:

```
class UsersFiltersNoAuth implements FilterInterface
{
    /**
     * Do whatever processing this filter needs to do.
     * By default it should not return anything during
     * normal execution. However, when an abnormal state
     * is found, it should return an instance of
     * CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response. If it does, script
     * execution will end and that Response will be
     * sent back to the client, allowing for error pages,
     * redirects, etc.
     *
     * @param \CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request
     * @param array|null                         $params
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $params = null)
    {
        // if no user is logged in then send them to the login form
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
        {
                        
            return redirect()->to('/user/index');
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Allows After filters to inspect and modify the response
     * object as needed. This method does not allow any way
     * to stop execution of other after filters, short of
     * throwing an Exception or Error.
     *
     * @param \CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface  $request
     * @param \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response
     * @param array|null                          $arguments
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}   // End of UsersFiltersNoAuth Class.
```

```
class UsersFiltersAuth implements FilterInterface
{
    /**
     * Do whatever processing this filter needs to do.
     * By default it should not return anything during
     * normal execution. However, when an abnormal state
     * is found, it should return an instance of
     * CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response. If it does, script
     * execution will end and that Response will be
     * sent back to the client, allowing for error pages,
     * redirects, etc.
     *
     * @param \CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request
     * @param array|null                         $params
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $params = null)
    {
        // if no user is logged in then send them to the login form
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
        {
            
            session()->set('redirect_url', current_url());
            
            return redirect()->to('/login');
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Allows After filters to inspect and modify the response
     * object as needed. This method does not allow any way
     * to stop execution of other after filters, short of
     * throwing an Exception or Error.
     *
     * @param \CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface  $request
     * @param \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response
     * @param array|null                          $arguments
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}   // End of UsersFiltersAuth Class.
```

if i try to go to /user/chengeEmail or /user/changePassword when ($_SESSION['user_id] is set) i am redirect to /user/index why ?

Moreover there is a way to apply a filter to an entire controller ? except some method ?

Comment: You need to read - https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html again

Comment: why ? https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#applying-filters

Comment: it works if i change isset($_SESSION['user_id]) with  session()->get('user_id') why ?

Comment: Ok, so you need to read about debugging - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406171/php-var-dump-vs-print-r and Sessions: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session