# Difference between var_dump,var_export & print_r

Tags: php

What is the difference between `var_dump`, `var_export` and `print_r` ?

Comment: @Your Common Sense S.O. answers are often clearer, more concise, actionable and basically always easier to reference than the PHP manual.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

[**var_dump**](http://php.net/var_dump) is for debugging purposes. `var_dump` always prints the result.

```
// var_dump(array('', false, 42, array('42')));
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(0) ""
  [1]=> bool(false)
  [2]=> int(42)
  [3]=> array(1) {[0]=>string(2) "42")}
}
```

[**print_r**](http://php.net/print_r) is for debugging purposes, too, but does not include the member's type. It's a good idea to use if you know the types of elements in your array, but can be misleading otherwise. `print_r` by default prints the result, but allows returning as string instead by using the optional `$return` parameter.

```
Array (
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] => 42
    [3] => Array ([0] => 42)
)
```

[**var_export**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) prints valid php code. Useful if you calculated some values and want the results as a constant in another script. Note that `var_export` can not handle reference cycles/recursive arrays, whereas `var_dump` and `print_r` check for these. `var_export` by default prints the result, but allows returning as string instead by using the optional `$return` parameter.

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => false,
  2 => 42,
  3 => array (0 => '42',),
)
```

Personally, I think `var_export` is the best compromise of concise and precise.

Comment: Note that `var_export`, due to its nature, will die a horrible recursive death on, well, recursive arrays. `print_r` and `var_dump` (though, not perfectly sure about latter, since I don't usually use it) don't have that issue. So don't `var_export($_GLOBALS);`, for example (which contains itself). :)

Comment: @ftrotter I always thought the comment would explain that curiosity well, but there you go, added a short note to the answer.

Comment: It should be added that you can make print_r() and var_export() return a string instead of outputting it, while var_dump() can't do it.
Also, I don't like var_export() since it's confusing - if you try to export some undefined constant SOMECONST, you'll just get back a text string 'SOMECONST'. So it won't say NULL, 0, "", but it will actually presume it's a string (and I suppose throw a NOTICE too).

Comment: var_export is good for safely representing a string, like quote/backslash protection.

Comment: Any idea why `var_export` has a trailing comma after the last array item?

Comment: @WebChemist Why not? It's easier to implement that way, and if I decide to use the output somewhere, I can simply add a line without worrying about having to modify the previously last line.

Comment: Personally I prefer `var_dump` output. Too bad it does not allow returning the output as a string. As such I can relate to @iconoclast's sentiment in the comment above. But having to choose `var_export` over `var_dump` for this use case is acceptable to me. For completeness, note this related [feature request](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73811).

Comment: `print_r` is useful to see the `structure` of your data in a clean and concise manner. It does not include types information, as said already, thus a lot more usable for casual investigation of data structures.

Comment: @Ricardo Martins Huh? Both with `var_export` and `var_dump`, this outputs `0.85`. In any case, the code `floatval(number_format(...))` is buggy – note what happens if the input is 1234.5!

Answer (score 4):

`var_dump` and `var_export` relate like this (from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php))

> var_export() gets structured
>   information about the given variable.
>   It is similar to var_dump() with one
>   exception: the returned representation
>   is valid PHP code.

They differ from `print_r` that `var_dump` exports more information, like the datatype and the size of the elements.