# Strange Unaccepted PHP Regex Pattern

Tags: php, regex

So, in the process of trying to bug fix an unexpected error, I have come to the conclusion that the following is somehow unacceptable in php:

```
$pattern = "/\/sc2\/en\/profile\/693604\/1\/EGIdrA\/ladder\/";
$subject = "\/sc2\/en\/profile\/693604\/1\/EGIdrA\/ladder\/";
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $result);
```

I have no idea how or why - all I know is that if I have this line, then various debugging echoes of various words at various locations both before and after this line are no longer echoed.  There are no loops anywhere, so I am quite confused as to why this is causing a problem.

Comment: So after this line the page just does nothing? Have you excluded this and tested it in a new script?

Comment: Yes, after this line, which is expected to return false, the page does nothing.  Furthermore, if this line is here, then some things before this line no longer function either.  Commenting out this line fixes everything. What I mean is, for example, 

echo "Test line 1";
//The line in question
echo "Test line 2";

IF the line in question is not commented out, then neither "Test line 1" nor "Test line 2" get echoed.  If however I comment out the line, then both test lines are echoed.  If I fix the preg_match() so that there is a match, then no such error occurs.

Comment: You've introduced a syntax error `$subject ='...'l` in process of editing the question too. But I couldn't change it as edits must be at least 6 characters different.

Comment: And just to be clear - the each echo and the line in question are on their own line.  Apparently I can't newline in comments here :/

Comment: Yea, the 1 at the end of line 2 is supposed to be a ; but that syntax error is of course not in the code.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to escape slashes in strings. `'\/'` is the same as `'\\/'`, i.e. the string `\/`.

In regular expressions, `\/` escapes a slash if you're using slashes to terminate the expression. You don't need that, simply choose another terminator, like `#`:

```
preg_match('#^/sc2/en/profile/693604/1/EGIdrA/ladder/$#',
           '/sc2/en/profile/693604/1/EGIdrA/ladder/', $result);
```

A single call to `preg_match` **does not halt execution** of a program. However, a variety of errors and warnings can be emitted - for example, you're missing a terminating `/` in the regular expression which yields

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found
```

Check your server's php settings (namely [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [log_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors)) for warning and error output configuration. On many systems, `/var/log/apache*/error.log` contains all php errors and warnings. Note that a set [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) can modify the output and make it an invalid XML document or confuse advanced output buffering.

Comment: My PHP error log actually shows no errors within the last 10 hours.  Actually have a further even more confusing result, wherein matches are found but print_r is not printing correctly... for instance my output is 

Array 
( 
    [0] => 

Note the lack of closing brace..

Comment: @Zhe Zhang That means it is probably misconfigured. In a development environment, you should always set `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` (you can check with `phpinfo()`). It would be great if you could produce a minimal `print_r` example that just prints out `Array ( [0] =>` and ask why in a new question (maybe give me a pointer).

Comment: Ah... it's a negative preg_match result that is causing the print_r to break mid execution... really weird.

Comment: Curiously if I copy paste it in to a new file a negative preg_match result does NOT cause execution break.  Instead print_r shows an empty array like I expect.

Comment: Meh, 2shared turned into an html file, but here it is: (I bet I did some horrrrible mistake at 5am haha) http://www.2shared.com/file/J8mhTLoB/bnet_parser.html

Comment: @Zhe Zhang That means surrounding code is responsible for the problem. Is the array recursive? Are you using output buffering? Edit: NVM, looking at the code ...

Comment: I managed to create a short 8 line bit of code which exhibits the same breaking of output.  Whatever is causing is there is likely the same as in the larger file: http://www.2shared.com/file/SzeWK344/testbug.html

Comment: @Zhe Zhang I got a shorter one: `print_r(array('<a'));`. The problem relates to `print_r`. use the way better `var_export` instead. Shameless self-promotion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039431/difference-between-var-dump-var-export-print-r .

Comment: Ah.  Though, the pattern '/<a[[:space:]]*href="\/sc2\/en\/profile\/693604\/1\/EGIdra\/"/'  should still match up with the pattern '<a href="/sc2/en/profile/693604/1/EGIdrA/"', no?  print_r or var_export, both are giving an empty array as the result of preg_match.

Comment: @Zhe Zhang Got it! It's a chromium/chrome bug. Works fine with firefox. You can temporarily add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` on top of the php document to make the problem go away.

Comment: omg wtf it magically matches up and works now, how the hell did you ever think of that O.O

Comment: And what's the cause of that chrome bug anyways, just curious if you happen to know.

Comment: @Zhe Zhang I filed a bug report, should be fixed relatively soon: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84179 . By the way, I can't not notice you are parsing HTML with regular expressions. In many cases, it's way easier to parse HTML with XML+xpath.

Answer (score 2):

Here's why:

```
preg_match('/^\/$/', '\/'); // false
preg_match('/^\/$/', '/'); // true
```

Comment: Hmm, I expected it to return false, but what surprised me was that it completely broke execution of the script, in that test echoes no longer appeared.

Comment: oops, didnt mean to hit enter.  But, changing it did fix everything.  Do false returns really screw with script execution that much? o.o

Answer (score 0):

You should not escape slashes `/` in input string, it's enough to escape them in pattern

```
preg_match('/^\/sc2\/en\/profile\/693604\/1\/EGIdrA\/ladder\/$/',
       '/sc2/en/profile/693604/1/EGIdrA/ladder/', $result);
```

(or like phihag mentioned, use i.e. # for pattern termination)

Comment: Is having the escape slashes in the input what caused the line to not execute though?  I did expect it to not match - but I didn't expect it to halt script execution.

Comment: @Zhe Zang No, not exactly. I updated my answer thusly. Please note that `echo` is not a reliably debugging utility due to output (and other) buffering. I updated my answer to include a short primer on warning and error logging.

Comment: i would say that "escaping" slashes in input isn't really escaping slashes, since they are not expected to be escaped(in input string you would only escape quotes like \' ). So parser doesn't know what to do with escaping slash, since it's not escaping anything. You have to or not use \ or if you want it in that input string use \\