# sorting array based on string value using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array ( [FAIL ] => 2 [PASS ] => 65 [NA] => 3 )
```

I want to display this array like :

```
Array([PASS] => 65 [FAIL] => 2 [NA] => 3)
```

Please help me on this one. Thank you.

Comment: On what basis you are sorting the array ?

Comment: plz show some code how you get this array

Comment: I don't see any basis for sorting of the array. Neither array's `keys` nor `values` are in any order.

Comment: iam getting records from database and iam changing that records into array based on some id

Comment: Hi Jenz, iam not sorting this array, iam aksing for help that how to display array like that

Comment: string comparision is also ok but i want the code display array like that

Comment: Why do you need to sort the array this way? It feels like the design is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your own sort order with [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

```
$keyValues=Array("Pass" => "Fail" => 2 "NA" => 1);
function keyValueSort($keyA,$keyB){
    if($keyA==$keyB){
        return 0;
    }
    return ($keyValues[$keyA] < $keyValues[$keyB]) ? -1 : 1;
}

uksort($yourArray, "keyValueSort");
```

Comment: Hi Mark Smit, it's not sorting again i am getting array like Array ( [FAIL ] => 2 [PASS ] => 65 [NA] => 3 )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039431/difference-between-var-dump-var-export-print-r in that case..