# print php variable in PHP-readable form

Tags: php, arrays

I have a need to print a complex PHP variable that can be pasted into code directly.  `print_r` doesn't do it as when I use it, I get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [cost] => 218.16
    [discount] => Array(...)
    [description] => Cost Not Included
    [quantity] => 1
)
```

which cannot be immediately pasted into PHP code.  I instead need something like so (with commas added, brackets changes to ampersands, etc)

```
array
(
    'cost' => '218.16',
    'discount' => array(...),
    'description' => 'Cost Not Included',
    'quantity' => 1,
),
```

How?

Currently I do it manually in my text editing program...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create array printed with print\_r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/create-array-printed-with-print-r)

Comment: linked question convert output of `print_r` into PHP readable form.  Similar in a roundabout way, but not the same as printing out an array in PHP readable form as the first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  :

```
var_export( $array );
```

It will print it.
Or if you want it in a string, then:

```
var_export($array, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the `var_export` function as described from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039431/difference-between-var-dump-var-export-print-r).