# print_r or echo the variable to see what the id is equal to

Tags: php, terminal, echo

[image]

I know by looking in the database that CL1 is equal to 6. How would i print_r or echo out this statement below. Also is there a way to just echo it out in terminal? I know if i change CL1 to Taxable Goods it would echo out a different id.. 2. I'm just not sure how to actually do it..

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); // Might not need this if product is already loaded
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('tax_class_id');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId('CL1');
}
```

Do i wrap the whole statement or just try to echo out the $optionId variable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) instead.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: That moment when you rollback at the same time as someone else...

Answer (score 1):

to log it in the console: (edited)

```
echo("<script>console.log('".$optionId."');</script>");
```

print it out:

```
print($optionId); //or
echo($optionId);
```

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on how to use the console.log... run that inside of my terminal? Do i have to be in the same directory or same page?

Comment: I got it to print on the page but still a bit confused on how to do it inside my terminal using ubuntu/bash

Comment: console.log wont put it in the terminal console, but into the browsers console. i'm affraid i wouldn't know how to watch it from outside the browser, unless you were to put a watch against it in your IDE. I, personally, just use the browsers console to print out any debugging i do.

Comment: How can the accepted answer to a PHP question be one that suggests using the **JavaScript** console?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for printing purpose you better you `var_export()` please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039431/difference-between-var-dump-var-export-print-r) link.

Comment: How would i use var export with that class and that if statement.. I just want to know the id of that variable.