# Notice: Array to string conversion PHP 3

Tags: php

im getting this error :

**( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\gcm\ind.php on line 14**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'db.php';
$com = new DbConnect();
$message=array();
$sql="select UTLR_UID from adm_utilisateurs where UTLR_LOGIN='groom' and UTLR_MDP='groomftw'";
$result=mysqli_query($com->getDb(),$sql);
$getID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$userID = $getID['UTLR_UID'];
$sqli = "SELECT AHIS_DATEHEURE,AHIS_DES_LN1 FROM alr_historiques WHERE UTLR_UID=$userID ";
$resulti = mysqli_query($com->getDb(),$sqli);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulti))
$message[]=$row['AHIS_DATEHEURE'].$row['AHIS_DES_LN1'];
```

//14

```
echo $message;


?>
```

Comment: $message is an array, you cant jsut 'echo' it. for debugging best way to view an array is `print_r($message)`, or `var_dump($message)`

Comment: Try change `$message[]=$row['AHIS_DATEHEURE'].$row['AHIS_DES_LN1'];` to `$message .=$row['AHIS_DATEHEURE'].$row['AHIS_DES_LN1']."<br/>\n";`

Comment: the problem is the same but i can see the message Array2018-04-16hello

Comment: Change `$message=array();` to `$message="";`

Comment: ahh, probably one of the includes then, they count for the line neuumbers

Comment: @Mr.Blue Thank you !

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff in here that would suggest it's not actually PHP 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

`void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )`

`echo` **only** able to output data of `string` type ,
or other data that can be directly converted to `string` ,such as `boolean`,`int`,`null`,`float`.

I just noticed that you are in `php 3` , you can try this

```
foreach($message as $m){
   //need to ensure that $m is a string type
   echo $m;
}
```

see more :

[What is the difference between var_dump, var_export and print_r ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039431/difference-between-var-dump-var-export-print-r)

I'm new to stackoverflow, Hope can help you.