# Why is PHP private variables got public when extended class

Tags: php

I created the follow class
PHP ver 5.5

```
abstract class Model
{
    var $id;

    private $cName;
    private $tName;

    public function __construct($id = 0)
    {
        $this->cName = 'Im cName';
        $this->tName = 'Im tName';            
    }
}
```

then an extended class

```
class claseExtend extends Model
{
    var $id;

    public function hola()
    {
        $this->id = 1;
        return (array) $this;
    }
}
```

if I Execute this:

```
$obj = new claseExtend() ;
$retHola =$obj->hola();
print_r($retHola);
```

I was Expecting to get: array(id => 1)

But the output is: array( \u0000Model\u0000cName: => 'Im cName',
        \u0000Model\u0000tName => 'Im tName')

What Am I doing wrong, or why is this happening if the attributes are private?

¿Why the array cast includes the private properties?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to serialize / dump the object from the outside, inside `hola` you are in the objects scope and have access the the protected/private methods and properties of that object. Ie: `$foo = new claseExtend(); print_r((array) $foo);`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10249647/697370

Comment: `private` variables are still inherited and available within the class. What you can't do is access them from outside the class like this: `$foo = new claseExtend; echo $foo->cName;`

Comment: Actually ,private properties are not inherited, but protected properties are.
you can see that if you run print($this->cName) you will get undefined variable, so I think print_r is just showing parent class private properties for debugging purposes

Comment: They are inherited, but no accessible  from child classes.

Comment: thanks for your comments I Have edited the question to manage the return of the function.
I think the cast (array) is making something strange there

Comment: Your code should be throwing errors about trying to access `$this` in a static function (hola)? Please switch on error reporting. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: imo, It would help us all if we start with valid PHP code before trying to explain the behaviour?

Comment: imo, Explaining why PHP does the actions it does, when all the code is valid, can be 'interesting'. ... This situation ... I have no idea. I suspect most of it is not important. i.e. just a consequence of how PHP works. Whatever, the code isn't valid.

Comment: I'm sorry,  I  have fixed the bug.  I'm using 5.5 php version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you cast an object to an array, private and protected properties are included in the result. The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says:

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

Those null bytes are shown in your results as `\u0000`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I can't understand why is that acceptable if it is a private member

Comment: They're given very weird names, so it's hard to access them inadvertently.

Answer (score 5):

`print_r` is a special magic function that will show the class including private and protected properties. It's a debugging utility function. Quoting from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r), [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) and [`var_export()`](http://php.net/var_export) will also
>   show protected and private properties of objects with PHP 5. Static
>   class members will not be shown.

In PHP, private properties *are* inherited in derived classes, but they are not accessible.

Comment: It is curious that if I change the print_r for a return is return the same thing

Comment: But he's not using `print_r()` on the object. He's converting the object to an array with `(array)$this`, and printing that. The question is why the cast includes the private properties.