# Allow accessing private variables PHP (var_dump, debugging)

Tags: php, xdebug, private, grpc

Is it possible to allow accessing private variables and members for debugging purpose.

Because, currently I am using `GRPC and Protobuff` in my PHP code. And when I try to dump or debug objects for GRPC communication I always get the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot access private properties. in

And as a result I am not able to debug my application properly.

Please suggest what to do in that case

Comment: It would help if you showed code (a [mcve], specifically) that demonstrates what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: You can use `var_dump()` on the object you want to debug to show the properties of that object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can var\_dump ascertain values of private variables, yet it can't when trying to access a single the property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249647/why-can-var-dump-ascertain-values-of-private-variables-yet-it-cant-when-trying)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code which throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

At least if you install *xdebug*, `var_dump` will list private properties of instances.

```
class Test
{
  private $x=1;
  private $y=2;
}

$test = new Test();

var_dump($test);
```

> object(Test)[1]
>
> private 'x' => int 1
>
> private 'y' => int 2

You can even run PHP in single steps (trace mode) and inspect and manipulate any property and variable from within your IDE at runtime after each expression.

Comment: @bxfvgekd Have you installed xdebug? I recommend Netbeans, Eclipse or PHPStorm as IDE.

Comment: Sure, this problems seems to related with GRPC