# json_encode vs var_dump on mysqli_connection

Tags: php, json

We have a `$link` variable like so:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
```

`var_dump($link);` returns the correct values for the keys:

```
["affected_rows"]=>  int(0)
["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - ..."
["client_version"]=> int(50011)
...
```

but `json_encode($link)` returns all nulls:

```
"affected_rows": null,
"client_info": null,
"client_version": null,
...
```

Is there a way to get the json_encoded string to have the same values?

Answer (score 1):

From [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> Parameters
>
> value
>
> The value being encoded. Can be any type except a resource.

You supplied `$link` which is [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

From [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/json_encoder.c#L550) it seems that for unsupported types (like resource) it will yield `"null"` value:

```
    default:
        encoder->error_code = PHP_JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE;
        if (options & PHP_JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR) {
            smart_str_appendl(buf, "null", 4);
   }
```

Comment: This is true, but the question is not whether `json_encode` could do the encoding, it can't and I am aware of the fact. The question is: *Is there a way to get the json_encoded string to have the same values?*

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping someone had done this and could share the solution. No solution so far, so I'd make an attempt.

As pointed by @rkosegi, `$link` is a resource. As a result we should expect the following:

> `var_export` will cast the resource to an array (`mysqli::__set_state`) - so `null`s again
>   `foreach` also treats it as an array and gives us `null`s
>   `var_dump` could get the values ([but could not be easily captured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/139491/66580))
>   `print_r` however, gives us the values and could be saved

So, let's use `print_r`:

```
$raw = print_r($link, true);
```

With some string parsing, we could get what we want.

**Update** - added string parsing with a caveat (`error_list`):

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'lilo123', 'm1_s1');
$raw = print_r($link, true);
$raw = explode(PHP_EOL, $raw);
$link_arr = [];
foreach($link as $k => $v) {
  $match = array_filter($raw, function($var) use ($k) { return strpos($var, '['.$k.']'); });
  $val = array_values($match)[0];
  if(strpos($val, ' => ')) {
    $val = explode(' => ', $val)[1];
    $link_arr[$k] = $val;
  }
}
$link_json = json_encode($link_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $link_json;
```

Output:

```
{
    "affected_rows": "0",
    "client_info": "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $",
    "client_version": "50011",
    "connect_errno": "0",
    "connect_error": "",
    "errno": "0",
    "error": "",
    "error_list": "Array", <-- no good
    "field_count": "0",
    "host_info": "Localhost via UNIX socket",
    "info": "",
    "insert_id": "0",
    "server_info": "5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1",
    "server_version": "50719",
    "stat": "Uptime: 52396  Threads: 1  Questions: 36754  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 133  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 60  Queries per second avg: 0.701",
    "sqlstate": "00000",
    "protocol_version": "10",
    "thread_id": "5274",
    "warning_count": "0"
}
```