# PHP String Comparison From Web Service

Tags: php, string, compare, strcmp, tradingview-api

*********** EDIT **********

There was a problem with control flow, I nested one if inside the other with a few other modifications, and it works. Thanks

I am having trouble with string comparison using PHP. I have a working copy of string comparison to isolate the issue. It works fine until I get data from a web service(TradingView). I have used "==", strcmp(), and strcasecmp(). All with no success. I am grabbing data from a web service, so maybe its the wrong character set? I am not sure. Here is the code.

```
    $entity = file_get_contents('php://input');

$txt = fopen("message.txt", "a");
fwrite($txt, $entity."\n");

    $elements = explode(" ", $entity);

    // 2. examine, elements[4] must be buy or sell to continue

    $position = $elements[4];

    if(strcasecmp($position, "buy") != 0){  
            fwrite($txt, "Not equal $position and buy\n");
            exit(0);
    }

    if(strcasecmp($position, "sell") != 0 ){ //strcmp($var1, $var2) !== 0
            fwrite($txt, "\"$position\" is not buy or sell, exiting\n");
            exit();
    }
```

I have used every string comparison I can find with zero luck. Please advise.

Comment: Can you show us what the "string" looks like?

Comment: To check what the data contains, try using `var_dump($position);` as it shows how many chars it thinks it contains.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the string should be "buy" or "sell"

Comment: @NigelRen i am running this process on the background where i can not get stdout. its like running it from the webserver aka cgi so there is trouble getting $position from var_dump when I can not get stdout

Comment: Have a read of [How can I capture the result of var_dump to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139474/how-can-i-capture-the-result-of-var-dump-to-a-string)

Comment: under the file_get_contents call.. add `file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($entity, true))` then paste back the result which will be stored in debug.txt to your question.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for replying, i get "string(3) "buy"

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I do not see a debug.txt file