# Pass a PHP variable to a JavaScript variable

Tags: php, javascript, escaping, newline

What is the easiest way to encode a PHP string for output to a JavaScript variable?

I have a PHP string which includes quotes and newlines.  I need the contents of this string to be put into a JavaScript variable.

Normally, I would just construct my JavaScript in a PHP file, à la:

```
<script>
  var myvar = "<?php echo $myVarValue;?>";
</script>
```

However, this doesn't work when `$myVarValue` contains quotes or newlines.

Comment: Just wanted to point out you can use `utf8_encode()` before passing the string to `json_encode`. That's what I'm doing: `echo json_encode(utf8_encode($msg));`

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript. The latter speaks about AJAX etc. and networking questions, whereas here it's about encoding/escaping/quotes and newlines. Let's reopen? (Btw, here the accepted is short, works good and has many hundreds of votes)

Answer (score 560, accepted):

Expanding on someone else's answer:

```
<script>
  var myvar = <?= json_encode($myVarValue, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>;
</script>
```

Using [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) requires:

- PHP 5.2.0 or greater
- `$myVarValue` encoded as UTF-8 (or US-ASCII, of course)

Since UTF-8 supports full Unicode, it should be safe to convert on the fly.

Please note that if you use this in html attributes like onclick, you need to pass the result of json_encode to htmlspecialchars(), like the following:

```
htmlspecialchars(json_encode($string), ENT_QUOTES);
```

or else you could get problems with, for example, `&bar;` in `foo()&&bar;` being interpreted as an HTML entity.

Comment: If you use UTF-8 that's the best solution by far.

Comment: It is important that the implementation of json_encode escapes the forward slash. If it didn't, this wouldn't work if $myVarValue was "</script>". But json_encode does escape forward slashes, so we're good.

Comment: If you're not 5.2, try jsonwrapper from boutell.com http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html

Comment: If you're using this in portable (e.g. library) code, there's one caveat.  json_encode() has been [reported as broken](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7462419).  It's fixed for me (5.4.4-7 on debian), but I don't know about earlier versions.

Comment: Be aware that PHP 5.3 now has options for escaping various characters. See example #2 for various outputs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Please note that if you use this in `onclick` attributes and the like, you need to pass the result of `json_encode` to `htmlspecialchars`, like the following: `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($string),ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8')` or else you could get problems with, for example, `&bar;` in `foo()&&bar;` being interpreted as an HTML entity.

Comment: Worked great thanks!  Also so others don't run into the same thing I did when using this:  Make sure to remove the quotes around your json_encoded php variables you are inserting into javascript because json_encode already includes them.

Comment: If the string contains new line, then I think it will throw an error

Comment: A plain json_encode() call for escaping output is insecure. Adding JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_TAG as the second parameter helps in some cases, but it still allows you to inject some JS code like "1; alert(10)" or something more harmful in an example like this. Other than proper input validation, I'm not sure what can help that case. Without the second param, injecting any code is trivial.

Comment: I think the best way on PHP 5.4+ to use two good special flags. And of course, the short syntax. Here is it: `var myvar = <?=json_encode($myVarValue, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)?>;` . The first one tells not to encode forward slash `/`, the second one prints any utf8 symbols not like `xNNNN` but just as is.

Comment: @FlameStorm: Encode forward slashes, that is useful to prevent `</script>` injections (!!) as they become `<\/script>`. Otherwise the script tag is closed prematurely which can be used as part of an attack. - see as well the earlier comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines#comment4081798_169035

Comment: @hakre: But how PHP string contains `"...</script>..."` can become JS non-string `</script>` instead of just JS string `"...</script>..."` after PHP's json_encode? It always add quotes for string. So, `var x = "...</script>...";` is just an JS string. No break.

Comment: For those using Laravel, you can use the ultra-simple `@json($myVarValue)`. See "Rendering JSON" under https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data

Comment: There are edge cases where json_encode() is not enough: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-escaper/escaping-javascript/

Comment: hello, please does anyone know why I'm getting `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` when using `var a = <?php  echo json_encode($_REQUEST["errors"]); ?>;`, thank you

Answer (score 27):

encode it with JSON

Comment: Probably the easiest way to get this to work 100% of the time. There are too many cases to cover otherwise.

Comment: Json only works with UTF-8 Charset. So it is not a solution if your website is working in a non UTF-8 Encoding

Comment: @nir: on one hand, i don't know any reason to use any other encoding, on the other hand, a full JSON encoder also manages any needed charset conversion

Comment: Encoding it with JSON is not enough, you also have to make sure that any Javascript string which contains `</script>` (case insensitive) is dealt with properly.

Comment: My only qualm with this is that encoding it with json will force it to an object. In practice, its easier to understand, but when you get to complex arrays of data, specifically that of reading SQL results out from a database, the programmer will need more indepth knowledge of javascript to efficiently handle the data.

Essentially what I am saying is that an example of the usage scenario would be great.

Comment: Encoding a single scalar value with JSON won't force it to an object - you just get a utf-8 string.  For example let's say your php code looks like this: $x="<script>alert('xss!');</script>";  and your HTML looks like this: <script>var x=<?= json_encode($x);?></script>  the result in the browse will be: <script>var x="<script>alert('xss!');<\/script>"</script>  Note the double quotes ahd the escaped slash.

Answer (score 24):

```
function escapeJavaScriptText($string)
{
    return str_replace("\n", '\n', str_replace('"', '\"', addcslashes(str_replace("\r", '', (string)$string), "\0..\37'\\")));
}
```

Comment: I needed this one because I was using the contents of the variable as part of a concatenated javascript expression.

Comment: This really helped me.

Answer (score 22):

I have had a similar issue and understand that the following is the best solution:

```
<script>
    var myvar = decodeURIComponent("<?php echo rawurlencode($myVarValue); ?>");
</script>
```

However, the [link](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/) that micahwittman posted suggests that there are some minor encoding differences. PHP's `rawurlencode()` function is supposed to comply with [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738), while there appear to have been no such effort with Javascript's `decodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent` complies with RFC 3986, I believe.

Comment: This is the correct solution when you parse large strings (ex: html content as string)

Comment: @RaduGheorghies Why?

Answer (score 12):

The paranoid version: [Escaping every single character](http://sixohthree.com/241/escaping).

```
function javascript_escape($str) {
  $new_str = '';

  $str_len = strlen($str);
  for($i = 0; $i < $str_len; $i++) {
    $new_str .= '\\x' . sprintf('%02x', ord(substr($str, $i, 1)));
  }

  return $new_str;
}
```

**EDIT:** The reason why `json_encode()` may not be appropriate is that sometimes, you need to prevent `"` to be generated, e.g.

```
<div onclick="alert(???)" />
```

Comment: Escaping every single character worked for me. json_encode doesn't handle backslashes very well. If you need to pass something like a regular expression from mysql to javascript as a parameter then this seems the best way.

Comment: @kristoffer-ryhl correctly remarks that dechex doesn't work for '\t' (= '\x08'), so I edited it to use sprintf. However, this still doesn't seem to work for UTF-8 characters (this would require using '\u' instead) ...

Comment: For an HTML attribute, you could do `<div onclick="alert(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($var));?>" />`

Comment: This is not unicode save, check this out: https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-escaper/escaping-javascript/

Answer (score 6):

```
<script>
var myVar = <?php echo json_encode($myVarValue); ?>;
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
var myVar = <?= json_encode($myVarValue) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: You must not enclose the encoded value in quotes.

Comment: Note that json_encode escapes forward slashes, meaning that this will never print `</script>` by accident.

Comment: How it's different from the accepted answer written 4 years prior?

Answer (score 4):

Micah's solution below worked for me as the site I had to customise was not in UTF-8, so I could not use json; I'd vote it up but my rep isn't high enough.

```
function escapeJavaScriptText($string) 
{ 
    return str_replace("\n", '\n', str_replace('"', '\"', addcslashes(str_replace("\r", '', (string)$string), "\0..\37'\\"))); 
}
```

Comment: Me too! These two lines of code is the best thing that happened to php (at least IMHO). Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

You can insert it into a hidden DIV, then assign the innerHTML of the DIV to your JavaScript variable. You don't have to worry about escaping anything. Just be sure not to put broken HTML in there.

Comment: "not to put broken HTML in there", that means escaping 'HTML entities' (at the very least '<' and '&')

Comment: No, just don't close your container DIV prematurely.

Answer (score 3):

Don't run it though `addslashes()`; if you're in the context of the HTML page, the HTML parser can still see the `</script>` tag, even mid-string, and assume it's the end of the JavaScript:

```
<?php
    $value = 'XXX</script><script>alert(document.cookie);</script>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = <?= json_encode($value) ?>; // Use this
    var foo = '<?= addslashes($value) ?>'; // Avoid, allows XSS!
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm making a dumb mistake, but when I try to execute this code, I get the following console error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` ONLY when I'm referencing an external .js file, when it's inilne, it works fine.

Thoughts?

Comment: @RADMKT Just a guess, but if it's a .js file it probably isn't using PHP. Might be worth loading the external JS file in the web browser to see the code output.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don’t. Use Ajax, put it in `data-*` attributes in your HTML, or something else meaningful. Using inline scripts makes your pages bigger, and [could be insecure or still allow users to ruin layout](http://codepad.org/jQopjG0k), unless…
2. … you make a safer function:

   ```
   function inline_json_encode($obj) {
       return str_replace('<!--', '<\!--', json_encode($obj));
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `<!--` does not need to be escaped within a script block, the only thing that you need to watch out for within a valid Javascript string literal is `</script>`, and json_encode never outputs that because it escapes forward slashes.

Comment: @Flimm: Did you look at the codepad link? Try `<script>console.log("<!--<script>")</script><script>console.log(")/;alert('execute arbitrary code here');<!---->")</script>`, where the two strings passed to `console.log` are user-provided (i.e. the template looks like `<script>console.log({{ s1 }})</script><script>console.log({{ s2 }})</script>`, where `$s1` and `$s2` come from a bad JSON encoder). Granted, the second string contains an unescaped forward slash and the example is utterly contrived, but a malicious user could still cause a syntax error like this.

Comment: @Flimm: How this works: `<!--<script>` causes the legitimate `</script>` to be treated as code rather than as an ending tag.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myvar = unescape('<?=rawurlencode($myvar)?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't completely work. Try with this string:::   I'm wondering "hey jude" 'cause 1 + 1 < 5 :::        we still get &lt; so not a 100% bidirectional transliteration

Comment: `unescape` is now deprecated. Use `decodeURIComponent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars

Description

```
string htmlspecialchars ( string $string [, int $quote_style [, string $charset [, bool $double_encode ]]] )
```

Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with some of these conversions made; the translations made are those most useful for everyday web programming. If you require all HTML character entities to be translated, use htmlentities() instead.

This function is useful in preventing user-supplied text from containing HTML markup, such as in a message board or guest book application.

The translations performed are:

```
* '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
* '"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
* ''' (single quote) becomes '&#039;' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
* '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
* '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

http://ca.php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: This will only be the right solution if the content of the JS variable is actually supposed to be HTML, where a string token like &amp; has meaning.  Otherwise, it might be best to not convert them to entities.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is bad practice or no, but my team and I have been using a mixed html, JS, and php solution. We start with the PHP string we want to pull into a JS variable, lets call it:

```
$someString
```

Next we use in-page hidden form elements, and have their value set as the string:

```
<form id="pagePhpVars" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="phpString1" id="phpString1" value="'.$someString.'" />
</form>
```

Then its a simple matter of defining a JS var through document.getElementById:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    var moonUnitAlpha = document.getElementById('phpString1').value;
</script>
```

Now you can use the JS variable "moonUnitAlpha" anywhere you want to grab that PHP string value.
This seems to work really well for us. We'll see if it holds up to heavy use.

Comment: I have been doing this in my previous projects. Next time, I will try to use jQuery data.

Comment: remember to htmlencode your $someString... and while this is fine for input @value's, you have to be extra careful with href/src/onclick type attributes (try to white-list), as they can go straight into using the javascript: protocol, which is not protected against with html encoded values.

Comment: To be safe, you should really do `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($someString));?>"`.

Answer (score -3):

If you use a templating engine to construct your HTML then you can fill it with what ever you want!

Check out [XTemplates](http://www.phpxtemplate.org).
It's a nice, open source, lightweight, template engine.

Your HTML/JS there would look like this:

```
<script>
    var myvar = {$MyVarValue};
</script>
```