# how to convert object into string in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP ToString() equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/php-tostring-equivalent)

how to convert object into string in php

Actually i am dealing with web service APIs.i want to use output of one API as a input for another API. when i am trying to do this i got error like this:Catchable fatal error: Object of class std could not be converted to string in C:\ ...

this is the output of first API::stdClass Object ( [document_number] => 10ba60 ) now i want only that number to use as input for 2nd AP

print_r and _string() both are not working in my case

Comment: do you mean cast it to a string, like you might in C? Or view a direct visual representation of the data it contains?

Comment: Actually i am dealing with web service APIs.i want to use output of one API as a input for another API. when i am trying to do this i got error like this:Catchable fatal error: Object of class std could not be converted to string in C:\....

Comment: I think you'll have to give us more details.

Error shows that another API uses return from first one as a string. I think it all depends of what information is returned by the first API and what information second API wants.

Comment: this is the output of first API::stdClass Object ( [document_number] => 10ba60 ) 
now i want only that number to use as input for 2nd API

Comment: print_r and _string() both are not working in my case

Comment: JJ, i added your comments to the question, where they belong.

Comment: I use `json_encode()` to covert unpredictable variables, objects into string. It's a quick trick and can be understood on other platforms than PHP

Answer (score 96):

You can tailor how your object is represented as a string by implementing a `__toString()` method in your class, so that when your object is [type cast as a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) (explicit type cast `$str = (string) $myObject;`, or automatic `echo $myObject`) you can control what is included and the string format.

If you only want to display your object's data, the method above would work. If you want to store your object in a session or database, you need to [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) it, so PHP knows how to reconstruct your instance.

Some code to demonstrate the difference:

```
class MyObject {

  protected $name = 'JJ';

  public function __toString() {
    return "My name is: {$this->name}\n";
  }

}

$obj = new MyObject;

echo $obj;
echo serialize($obj);
```

Output:

> My name is: JJ
>
> O:8:"MyObject":1:{s:7:"*name";s:2:"JJ";}

Comment: That isn't serializing. Other than the serialize part though this is a very good explanation (especially the part about _implementing_ __toString())

Comment: Was this here before my answer?! Sorry, didnt see it. Deleted mine, upvoted yours.

Comment: __toString() & {$this->name}.  Excellent.  Just what I needed.

Answer (score 40):

Use the casting operator `(string)$yourObject;`

Comment: Works only if object can be casted to string, e.g. implements __toString(). Which it does not in this case, apparently.

Comment: This works best for converting object values to string ie. (string)$object->value 
Pretty much useful when we have mixed types to return.

Answer (score 17):

You have the `print_r` function, check [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Answer (score 9):

There is an [object serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) module, with the [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) function you can serialize any object.

Comment: but if the object has complex datatypes or resources you should work with it using magic functions => http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php like __wakeup or __sleep to serialize deserialize resources or complex datatypes.

Comment: According to php.net, when using serialize(), an attempt is made to call __wakeup/__sleep at the appropriate times automatically, so all you have to worry about is actually implementing the functions themselves. My guess though, is that this is a bit beyond what the requirements of the OP would be!

Answer (score 7):

In your case, you should simply use

```
$firstapiOutput->document_number
```

as the input for the second api.