# Can I change the variable type from object to string?

Tags: php, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert object into string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469222/how-to-convert-object-into-string-in-php)

I have a variable that contain some object (SimpleXML).
Can I change the type of this variable, and to assing it to this variable itself?
Like this:

```
$test = (string)$test;
var_dump($test);
```

The above code does not work, so the output is still `object(SimpleXMLElement)` and not a `string`.

But when I assign it another variable, like `$new_test = (string)$test` it works well, and the var_dump output is `string`]

Comment: there's no such thing as sring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469222/how-to-convert-object-into-string-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/php-tostring-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string content, use `asXML` method.

```
var_dump($test->asXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `SimpleXML` implements the magic function [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring). Its different from class to class. But if its not implemented, PHP will throw a fatal error.

So, typecasting directly from `object` to `string` does not work unless the `__toString()` method is implemented.

Comment: When I assign it to another variable [like this `$test2=(string)$test` it works well, and the var_dump output is `sring`]

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, since I don't see your code. But `$var = (string)$var;` is the same as `$var2 = (string)$var;` in the sense that `$var` and `$var2` will both contain the same content.

Comment: Thank you very much. you are right, it was another problem in the code. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an object to string just like adding a declaration, it might work but it wont behave like desired there's a greate article though written before here in stack on how you should do it the optimal way which is by adding a tostring method read more here...
[how to convert object into string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469222/how-to-convert-object-into-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Typecast the SimpleXMLObject to a string

```
$foo = array( (string) $xml->parent->child );

<?php
  $xmlstring = "<parent><child> hello world </child></parent>";
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
  $foo = array( (string) $xml->child );
  var_dump($xml).PHP_EOL;
  var_dump($foo);
?>
```

Output

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["child"]=>
  string(13) " hello world "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) " hello world "
}
```

http://codepad.org/Bss1rndd

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the object being converted. For SimpleXML you probably want its `asXML` method: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php. For general objects, you can typecast to string if the objects implements the `__toString()` method. Another option would be `var_export(...,true)`, but that is rarely useful except for debugging.