# Optimal way to convert stdClass Object array to string

Tags: php, foreach, implode, stdclass

Optimal way to convert stdClass Object array to string

my stdClass object format is:

```
$autoArea = Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [area] => aarea )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [area] => area )
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [area] => barea ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [area] => carea )
)
```

i need out put as string:

```
'aarea', 'area', 'barea', 'carea'
```

i tried below 2:

```
$areas="";
foreach($autoArea as $ar)
{
    if($areas=="")
    {
        $areas="'".$ar->area."'";
    }
    else
    {
        $areas=$areas.","."'".$ar->area."'";
    }
}
echo $areas;
```

and

```
$tp= array();
foreach($autoArea as $ar)
{
    $tp[] = $ar->area;
}

$areas=implode("','", $tp); 
$areas="'".$areas."'";
echo $areas;
```

Which one is more optimal, or any other suggest me.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469222/how-to-convert-object-into-string-in-php

Comment: @Suresh Kamrushi: i need which is the optimal way not the method to convert array to string, The best way according to performance and execution times etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract desired property, like:

```
$data = [
   (object)['area' => 'foo'],
   (object)['area' => 'bar'],
   (object)['area' => 'baz']
];
$result = join(',', array_map(function($x)
{
   return $x->area;
}, $data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_map](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function($item) {return $item->area;}, $autoArea));
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

json_encode($object) will turn it into a JSON string