# how to convert an object into a String?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting an output as object, but I want the record to be displayed in text.

[image]

Comment: Please do not upload images of your code! It is quite hard for us to easily modify and test your code if it is in image format. Could you update your question with the code text-based?

Comment: Write your code instead of uploading photo!

Comment: Don't use old deprecated `mysql_`-functions. Don't concatenate SQL queries from user provided data, use parameters. Explain exactly where you're getting this result and what debugging steps you took to find out what's happening.

Comment: Do you have html string in results array ?

Comment: For JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string
For PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469222/how-to-convert-object-into-string-in-php

Comment: my problem get solved.thank you so much .

Answer (score 0):

You mean in the content of "#bs" and "#cost"??
Use "JSON.stringify()" you know the function, you're using it in the code

Did you mean that?

Comment: yeah, using `JSON.stringify` and discarding the result

Answer (score 0):

If you get the object, you can transform it to string of fly, outputing its properties like that:

```
$('#bs).html(result[1].id + result[1].title);
```

corresponding to name of columns, you can also

```
console.log(result[1])
```

and check in console correct property names of the object