# Read PHP toString'd object in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Is there a convenient nodeJS parsing library or function to reverse a string which was generated via toString() in PHP?

For example I generate the string in PHP:

```
O:8:"MyObject":1:{s:7:"*name";s:2:"JJ";}
```

(stolen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469222/how-to-convert-object-into-string-in-php/2469269#:%7E:text=You%20can%20tailor%20how%20your,included%20and%20the%20string%20format.) example)

Now I'd like to reverse the operation in nodeJS to get a object back looking like:

```
{
  "name": "JJ"
}
```

Comment: Dude, what?!1! If you want/need to transfer/convert data between node&php, i (personal) would chose json.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It is not that I like to be a masochist. I have a legacy wordpress database where data was persisted this way. Since I want to read and migrate the data I'm looking for a lib/function before writing my own parser.

Comment: You can try to encode your data as json and see what comes out. But i hardly doubt that the example above is in any way a valid json string. But try it out, perhaps [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) filter the "crap" for you out. Then you are ready to go/use the json string in node.