# Why substr() doesn't work correctly with a number that has a leading zero?

Tags: php, substring

I have this script:

```
function DecryptId($id) {
    $first_digit = substr($id, 0,1);
    if ( $first_digit == 0 ) {
        return 'yes';
    } else {
        return 'no';
    }
}

$id = 014;
echo DecryptId($id);

//=> no
```

#### [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Snaaf)

Why it prints `no`? I expect it prints `yes`. Because the value of `$id` starts with `0`. What's wrong?

---

**EDIT:** In reality I'm passing `$id` like this: `DecryptId($_POST['au']);`. `$_POST['au']` is containing a number. Something like these:

```
23
43552
0153
314
09884
```

As you see, *sometimes* that number starts with `0`. And I need to pass it as a string. How can I do that?

Comment: Your id is a number not a string. So with the prefix 0 it is interpreted as octal number. Means: `$id = 12`

Comment: @Rizier123 I see. Is there any approach to gives me first digit?

Comment: Assign it as a string.

Comment: $id = 014; It should be $id = "014";

Comment: @Rizier123 [I did](https://3v4l.org/tAONG), but still it prints `no`.

Comment: @stack With this you basically do this: `(string)12`. You want: `$id = "014";$`

Comment: @Rizier123 May you please take a look at my **EDIT** part ?

Comment: Your `$_POST['au']` is string and it should work, just try.

Comment: @vp_arth You are right .. thx, Just I want `no` for this https://3v4l.org/k5uSl ..! Do you know how can I get that?

Comment: Use `$first_digit === '0'` :)

Comment: @vp_arth well done `:-)`

Comment: @vp_arth Also having a smile when you are talking with people is a sweet behavior  .. *(based on that smile-emoji which is in the end of the most of comments)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is working fine the issue is that you are passing a number in your function when you should provide a string. So in the case that your variable type is `integer` the leading zero will eventually ***fly*** away.

You can add something to your function to check the variable type and inform the user.

```
function DecryptId($id) {
    $type = gettype( $id );
    if($type!= "string") {
    echo "Your variable has type ".$type.". Use a 'string' type variable";
    return;
    }
    $first_digit = substr($id, 0,1);
    if ( $first_digit == 0 ) {
        return 'yes';
    } else {
        return 'no';
    }
}

$id = 014;
echo DecryptId($id);
echo "\n";
$id = '014';
echo DecryptId($id);
```

Try the above example in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00be0234d5a35167217e5058788815ae009299ee)

Comment: Ok, May you please take a look at **EDIT** part of the question?

Comment: You `strval` known string variable? :)

Comment: @vp_arth sorry mate that was forgotten there from sandbox test you are right. :)

Comment: @vp_arth the main part of the answer is the two lines that inform the user of the variabe type, otherwise a correct answer to this question is already given.

Comment: @stack in addition if your `$_POST` variable is in fact a number try adding a leading zero yourself based in the number's length in digits. If that umber has a fixed length e.g. 4 digits then try adding them inside the function using PHP's `str_pad`

Answer (score 4):

Because of the leading zero, PHP will be parsing that number as octal. Even if it didn't do this, most languages will strip off the leading zeros (since they don't actually form part of the number). This means that `$id` will evaluate to `12`.

Are you sure you don't want to declare it as a string? (`$id = "014"`)

Comment: I want to convert it to string and then use `substr()`. How can I convert it?

Comment: You can explicitly convert by casting to a string (e.g. `$foo = (string)14`), but this won't help in this case. The leading zero signals that the number is an octal and is then thrown away. `$id` literally does not contain a zero. Try `echo()`ing `$id` after you declare it to see.

Comment: If you want to specifically cast octal to string, refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495611/working-with-php-octals-and-string-conversions). Otherwise just wrap it with double or single quotes for it to be interpreted literally as a string.

Comment: Yeah. Only way around it is to ensure that your number is saved with leading zeros as a string in the first instance

Comment: Note also that even if you add more leading zeroes (e.g. `$id = 00000014`), they will still be thrown away. There's no way to do this without saving as a string like @Jonathan says.

Comment: Ok I initialize `$id` like this; `$id = $_POST['au']` *(`$_POST['au']` is containing a number that **sometimes** it starts with zero)*. How can I make it as a string?

Comment: The moment your input is captured, it must be saved as a string. Just debug to see what is coming over. Make adjustments from there

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php

function DecryptId($id) {
    $first_digit = substr($id, 0,1);

    if ( $first_digit == 0 ) {
        return 'yes';
    } else {
        return 'no';
    }
}

$id = '014';
echo DecryptId($id);
?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Come on now... if we all just copied the questioners code and flipped in the obvious suggestion we'd all be able to get cheap rep. Why are people coming in so graciously in upvoting this answer? It came after all comments had pointed out the problem and shows zero effort, and no explanation to back up his suggestion, nor *what* exactly he changed (even if its obvious). I cannot understand why people feel  it necessary to negate the valid downvotes here..