# Concat big integer into a string

Tags: php, integer, concatenation

I have multiple variables that stores int values.
I need to concat them into on variable. If I do a simple concat, I get a scientific value.
I need to work on the concatenated value as a string.

```
$val1 = 25019;
var_dump('val1 :'.$val1);
$val2 = 1000123;
var_dump('val2 :'.$val2);
$val3 = 00260;
var_dump('val3 :'.$val3);
$val = $val1.$val2.$val3;
var_dump('val :'.$val);
```

will display

```
string(11) "val1 :25019"
string(13) "val2 :1000123"
string(9) "val3 :176"
string(20) "val :250191000123176"
```

so $val3 is causing troubles (I guess because of the leading "0").

I tried with `$val3 = (string)00260;` but still the same result.
I can not simply put the value between "'" because I hardcoded them for the example, but in my code they are extracted from a varchar field in a database.

Comment: Leading 0 means that the number is octal.

Comment: Wrap the value in quotes to preserve leading zeros like  $val3 = '00260';

Comment: Thanks, I solved it with help of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495611/working-with-php-octals-and-string-conversions