# How to convert a PHP object to a string?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP ToString() equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/php-tostring-equivalent)

I get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

So, my question is, how do I convert an object to a string in PHP? I don't want to serialize it though.

Just a note: the code I use works in PHP 4, but not in PHP 5

Thanks!

EDIT: I resolved it myself. It was a pain, but I did it. Thanks anyway, everyone :-)

Comment: What's the context and purpose in which this will be used?

Comment: Its used in wordpress. I have an array of objects. I'm trying to store the 'slug' attribute of the objects in a string, but I get that error.

Comment: Serializing *is* converting to string, isn't it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Why do you need this string? If you just need to visualize it for debugging, you can use `var_dump()`, `print_r()`, or `$s = print_r($var, 1);` to really make it into a string for further theming. If you need to send the object as text to somewhere else (database, Javascript code), you have a choice of serialize, json_encode, XML conversion, and many more, depending on your exact situation.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm using this PHP snippet to create a string from a JSON object for a data attribute in my HTML. My JavaScript will then use the attribute value to filter data as needed. This came in handy!

Comment: does not answer the question

Answer (score 5):

### You want to convert a PHP object to a string?

if neither [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), [var_export](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) nor [__toString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) is exactly what you're after maybe this can help you satisfy your needs.

#### For PHP 5.3 and above

```
<?php
$v = (object) array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$r = new ReflectionObject($v);

echo $r->getName() .' {' . implode(', ', array_map(
     function($p) use ($v) {
         $p->setAccessible(true);
         return $p->getName() .': '. $p->getValue($v);
     }, $r->getProperties())) .'}';
```

Will output:

```
stdClass {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

#### For a more conventional approach compatible with previous PHP 5 flavours try

```
<?php
class ExampleClass {
    private $pvt = 'private';
    protected $prot = 'protected';
    public $pub = 'public';
}

$v = new ExampleClass();
$r = new ReflectionObject($v);

echo $r->getName() ." {\n";
foreach ($r->getProperties() as $p)
   if ($p->isPublic())
       echo "\tpublic ".$p->getName().': '.$p->getValue($v)."\n";
   else
       echo "\t".($p->isPrivate()?'private ':'protected ').$p->getName().",\n";
echo "}\n";
```

Which will print:

```
ExampleClass {
    private pvt,
    protected prot,
    public pub: public
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to add the magic method [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) to your class so you can print what you want.

Edit: Sorry, just saw "PHP 4, but not in PHP 5".

Comment: Once that's added, how does one invoke it from the object? directly?

Comment: just echo out the object instance like echo new Image($params);

Answer (score 1):

you can use php magic method [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)

Comment: You cannot implement __toString on StdClass.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is not a problem with the object not convertable to a string.

It's more like that you are assuming that a variable contains a string, (or something that can represented as a string), but it contains an object, and you are trying to echo that out.

Answer (score -1):

from the error you get I assume you used the object as a parameter to a function that expects a string. the question is, why you did that and what you expect that function to with the object. and then before passing it to the function, extract a sensible string value.

Answer (score -1):

You do not try to convert this Object in string,it will not work. Just fetch exact value from that Object.

As a example if you  got output as cost.this cost output is Object. so fetch exact value from this as follows

```
  $var=cost->Postage_cost;
  $var1=cost->other_cost;
```