# How to convert any object to a string, for debugging purposes?

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP ToString() equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/php-tostring-equivalent)
>   [How to convert a PHP object to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537767/how-to-convert-a-php-object-to-a-string)

I'm looking for a function that can take any kind of variable (primitive, object, array, ...) and convert it to a string, for debugging purposes.

This is [the best question I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/php-tostring-equivalent) about converting objects to strings. Its answers don't seem to contain a general purpose solution that can handles all kinds of objects. I've tried `(string)x`, `strval(x)` and `serialize(x)`, and also `json_encode(x)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836988/11236).

`(string)x` and `strval(x)` cause `Object of class Foo could not be converted to string`. `json_encode(x)` returns an empty string for me. `serialize()` does work, but its output is not only textual (it contains weird "NULLs" and is a bit hard to read.

I tried search Stack Overflow for `Object of class Foo could not be converted to string`, but found a ton of specific question that got zero upvotes and no general solutions.

**The question, again - how to pretty print / convert any php value into a string in php?**

Comment: I got my answer - it is actually the fifth answer on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3559247/11236 - voting to close this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually go for `print_r`, works great for me so far.

PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

> print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

Comment: I thought this answer was useless because `print_r` just didn't work for me, but then I realized print_r ***prints by default***, and does't return the correct value. Use `print_r(foo, true)` to return the value!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer:

```
print_r($object, true);
```

This does print a nice view of the object into a string.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for debugging the easiest solution is to use [print_r](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).
In case you display this in a HTML document you can wrap a `<pre>` tag around to have this formatted well readable.

```
<pre>    
<?php print_r( $object ); ?>
</pre>
```

Example output of

```
$object = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

print_r( $object );
```

`print_r` uses `\n` and `\t` to format:

```
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 0
    [client_info] => 5.1.62
    [client_version] => 50162
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] =>
    [errno] => 0
    [error] =>
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_count] => 0
    [host_info] => 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
    [info] =>
    [insert_id] => 0
    [server_info] => 5.5.20
    [server_version] => 50520
    [stat] => Uptime: 11556798  Threads: 2  Questions: 1351931648  Slow queries: 421  Opens: 225532  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 1017  Queries per second avg: 116.981
    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [protocol_version] => 10
    [thread_id] => 171160
    [warning_count] => 0
)
```

Comment: print_r doesn't work for me: `print_r(stateArr)` yields `1` while 
`serialize(stateArr)` yields `a:1:{s:5:"error";b:0;}`

Comment: `var_dump` is even worse, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: `print_r(foo, true)` works!

Comment: Yep, when you don't want to display the values you can pass true as a second parameter to return the result as a string.

Comment: You're welcome, vampire :)