# I want to use part of a pages URL as the page title using PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have hundreds of pages, each with a unique url. All the pages are the same with the exception of the url which is also the name of the page. How can i get the page to read the url and place the name (parsing the http://www. and the .tld? It needs to be both the Title of the page as well as be shown else where on the page. Can this be done in PHP?

Comment: Can you show which parts of the URL will form the name? Can you show an example?

Comment: So, If your URL was:  http://www.http://www.wordcutter.tld, you want to parse and set the <title> attribute of your page as "wordcutter"?

Answer (score 2):

If you use this code it will only grab the domain name without the http://www.  You can then use a substring query to remove the .tld.

```
<?php
# Using HTTP_HOST

$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domain = substr($domain, 0, -4);

echo "<title>" . $domain . "</title>";
?>
```

If you place this code in between the  tags , then you will get a dynamic title based on the URL.

Comment: here is just a quick html mark up of what a page blank looks like      <html>

<head>
<title>parsed url here </title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="blue" vlink="purple" alink="red">
<p>Welcome to &quot; url name inserted here&nbsp;&quot;</p>
</body>

</html>

Comment: here is a sample link to one of the pages... http://858.414.6744.us/demo2.php  you can see it is cutting off the last number in the sequence

Comment: Thank you for all the help.. the title is working perfect. now if i can get the domain name inserted into the page all would be right on track. can i use the same call used to get the title or are the tags different when they are in the body of the page?

Comment: The php code will remain the same whether it's in the head or the body.  However you only use <title> html tags in the <head> section.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to a page:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

You can now get the current page URL using the line:

```
<?php
  echo curPageURL();
?>
```

check [PHP: How to Get the Current Page URL](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php)

I didn't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: Now that we have the url as the title, can that same info be passed to other locations on the page ie,  " welcome to xxxxxxxxx "  xxxxxx being the parsed section of the url being used as the title?

Comment: I think you can do that pal. you can even turn $pageURL to a tring and use it too, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/php-tostring-equivalent