# Java String.valueOf to PHP

Tags: java, php, string

Hope all is well. So I am new to PHP and I have to write a program in it that basically parses through information. I have been doing oodles of research and finally found something that works for what I need but it is written in Java. I ran into a wall when I came to this (the 3rd line, tempChar)

```
for (counter = 0; counter <= htmlInput.length()-1; counter++){
  //place the current character in tempChar
  tempChar = String.valueOf(htmlInput.charAt(counter));
```

Is the equivalent of string.valueOf implode in php? I just need to return the string representation and store it's contents. Thank you so much for helping me while I am a noob at this.

Comment: valueOf will take that char and convert it into a String type. Are you sure you wanna do that?

Comment: Also have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/php-tostring-equivalent

Comment: What does the Java code actually do?

Comment: It will go through a html table and parse all the data, throwing into a .csv file. Here is a link to it: http://www.cs.iupui.edu/~aharris/H2Text.html

Comment: The page won't open here, but there are easier ways to do this - ie: parsing the HTML using an (X)HTML parser (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)) and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java code you posted looks like it's converting a `char` to a `java.lang.String`. This is necessary in java since it's a strongly typed language. PHP is loosely typed so you don't need to explicitly handle type conversions. The PHP conversion of the java code you found might look something like this:

```
for ($counter=0; $counter <= count($htmlInput) - 1; $counter++) {
    // place the current character in tempChar
    $tempChar = substr($htmlInput, $counter, 1);
```

BTW: [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in PHP is used to join elements of an array into a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (str_split($string) as $char) {
    ...
}
```

asking for equivalents of specific functions won't get you anywhere; you need to take a wider view to translate code effectively. In fact, even this is probably wrong, because there's a good chance that you don't need to loop over the characters in the string at all — but it's impossible to tell since you didn't provide any information about what you're *really* doing.

Comment: Hey Hobbs! Basically I am reading in a file, parsing through it, finding key terms, and throwing them out into a .csv file with php. The best example I have found, is here: http://www.cs.iupui.edu/~aharris/H2Text.java

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific character from a string in PHP treating the string like an array:

```
$tempChar = $htmlInput[$counter];
```

This would be basically the same thing.

(Another form I just learned about: `$htmlInput{$counter}` - notice the curly braces.)