# jsp unable to put session attribute into string

Tags: java, jsp

i'm having an issue with a session attriblute in a jsp page, i would like to pass it into a string so that i can use it to query a database eg,

```
String group=session.getAttribute("group");
```

i know it has been correctly populated because if i put the below in a page it displays the correct value

```
<%=
session.getAttribute("group")
 %>
```

the error i am getting is

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String

is there a different way to put a session variable into a String? or am i doing it completely wrong. any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: What is the `session` variable ? How do you get it ? Is it `HttpSession` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to cast it to `String`

```
String group=(String)session.getAttribute("group");
```

where  `session.getAttribute("group");`  returns `Object`.

Comment: i tried changing by code like you said but now get "string cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @Baadshah don't you think that import is default. I think its a typo.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao yes.But I just  make him cross check :) and finally he caught that typo.

Comment: @user2168435 No issues.Happens to every programmer :)

Comment: i prefer `String group=session.getAttribute("group").toString();`

Comment: @MaVRoSCy yes you are right ,but casting to a String is cheaper since that doesn't require an external function call, just internal type checking.

Answer (score 1):

`session.getAttribute(String name)` will return an `Object`.

To be safe and prevent any accidental `ClassCastException`, I would use `String.valueOf(Object obj)`, like this:

```
String group = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("group"));
```

Sources:

[Difference between casting to String and String.valueOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815279/difference-between-casting-to-string-and-string-valueof)

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score -2):

you  just put like this:

```
String group=""+session.getAttribute("group");
```

append as string, simple.