# Is it correct to convert 2D CharArray to String and use .charAt() to compare a character?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, multidimensional-array, charat

So I have a `char` variable called "temp" which I'd like to compare to the element stored in "X" `CharArray[X][Y]` while I'm in a third `for` loop after the 2D array.

For example:

```
char temp;
temp = ' ';
String end;
end = "";
for (int i = 0; i < CharArray.length; i++){
        for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++){
            if (somethingY){
                if (somethingZ){
                    for (int j = 0; j < something.length; j++){
                        //something
                        temp = somethingX;
                        if (temp == String.valueOf(CharArray[i][m]).charAt(0)){
                            end = String.valueOf(CharArray[i][m]);
                            System.out.print(end);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried printing "temp" where it says "temp = somethingX" and it prints just fine. But when I try to save the `String` into a `String variable`, it will not print the variable called "end".

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815279/difference-between-casting-to-string-and-string-valueof), it won't do anything if the object is something else, but "end" **is** a `String`.

So, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: In case there's a confusion, "I'm trying to `print` "end", but I figured if `temp == String.valueOf(CharArray[i][m]).charAt(0)` is correct, so should "end"'s part.".

EDIT2: Defined "temp" for people...

EDIT3: I tried "`end.equals(String.valueOf(CharArray[i][m]));`", but still nothing happens when I try to print it. I get no errors nor anything.

EDIT4: I tried putting `String.valueOf(CharArray[i][m]).charAt(0)` into a another variable called "temp2" and doing `if (temp == temp2)`, but still the same thing.

EDIT5: I tried `temp == CharArray[0][m]` and then `end = CharArray[0][m]`, but still nothing prints.

EDIT6: OK. Sense this will never get resolved, I'll just say the whole point of my problem. -> I have an `ArrayList` where each line is a combination of a letter, space and a number (e.g. "E 3"). I need to check if a letter is repeating and if it is, I need to sum the numbers from all repeating letters.

For example, if I have the following `ArrayList`:

```
Z 3
O 9
I 1
J 7
Z 7
K 2
O 2
I 8
K 8
J 1
```

I need the output to be:

```
Z 10
O 11
I 9
J 8
K 10
```

I didn't want people to do the whole thing for me, but it seems I've no choice, since I've wasted 2 days on this problem and I'm running out of time.

Comment: Unclear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to `print` "end", but I figured if `temp == String.valueOf(CharArray[i][m]).charAt(0)` is correct, so should "end"'s part.

Comment: It seems you are comparing references and not values. `temp` is not the same Object as `String.valueOf(CharArray[i][m]).charAt(0)`  You need `.equals()`

Comment: I know, but doesn't that reference still have a value, even if that value is variable and can change according to previous input?

Comment: @DoombringerBG, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Sure, the value of temp is `0xFE0176129` and the other value is `0xFF9002876`. :)

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko Why are you sending this? It has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: I don't know where you define `temp` but just change your if statement to `if (temp.equals(String.valueOf(CharArray[i][m]).charAt(0)))`

Comment: @jiveturkey Why would the value be that, if I have the previous things already set up thanks to all the `If`'s?

Comment: Copy/Paste error, read again

Comment: @jiveturkey "temp" is a `Char` so the `.equals()` doesn't work.
I even tried, just in case. xD

Comment: Probably try using String s=new String(new char[] {c});

Comment: Also, chars are ints, so you should be able to compare them : (int)temp==(int)temp2

Comment: @user7185318 Why is "c" in "{}"?
Also, the `Char` I'm trying to compare is a letter, not a number.

Comment: I mean chars are stored as ints.

Comment: c is just an example char.

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt got it, could you please clarify, maybe just in a comment, what you are attempting to do ? Input, expected output etc. ?

Comment: @user7185318 Re-read the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map :

```
ArrayList<String> input=new ArrayList<String>();
input.add("O 2");
input.add("O 2");
Map<String, Integer> map= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String s:input) {
     String[] splitted=s.split(" ");
     String letter=splitted[0];
     Integer number=Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
     Integer num=map.get(letter);
     if (num==null) {
         map.put(letter,number);
     }
     else {
         map.put(letter,number+num);
     }
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + Integer.toString(entry.getValue()));
}
```

---

Without using a map :

```
ArrayList<String> input=new ArrayList<String>();
input.add("O 2");
input.add("O 2");
ArrayList<String> letters=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String s:input) {
     String[] splitted=s.split(" ");
     String letter=splitted[0];
     Integer number=Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
     int index=-1;
     boolean isthere=false;
     for (String l:letters) {
          index++;
          if (l.equals(letter)) {
              isthere=true; //BUGFIX
              break;
          }
     }
     if (isthere==false) { //BUGFIX
         letters.add(letter);
         numbers.add(number);
     }
     else {
         numbers.set(index,numbers.get(index)+number);
     }      
}
for (int i=0; i < letters.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(letters.get(i));
     System.out.print(numbers.get(i));
}
```

---

Converting it back to have a nice output :

```
ArrayList<String> output=new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i < letters.size(); i++) {
    output.add(letters.get(i)+" "+Integer.toString(numbers.get(i));
}
```

Feel free to comment if you are having any questions.

Comment: I can't use `Map`, it's too advanced for me.
But I think using `.substring()` somehow might work, I'm just not sure how to go about it right now.

Comment: @DoombringerBG What do you mean with too advanced ?

Comment: As in, never seen it before.

Comment: @DoombringerBG So why cant you use it ? Have a look at the code. A map works very easy : Key - Value

Comment: @DoombringerBG : Have a look at my edit that is emulating a map.

Comment: I re-read the one without the `Map` several times to make sure I understand it correctly and now I think I do, but is there a way to save the final result in the same `input ArrayList`, because I'm not sure how I'm supposed to update it if the letters and numbers are in different `ArrayList`s.

Comment: @DoombringerBG : Please have a look at my second edit *Converting it back to have a nice output*

Comment: So, I checked a few times and even directly copy/pasted it, just to be sure I wasn't doing something wrong, and it doesn't seem to work properly.
When you have multiple different letters, it takes the first one and adds all of the numbers from the rest of the letters, but it doesn't separate them.
Could I have done something wrong or was that the original intent? I'll put more examples with letters in the original post.

Comment: @DoombringerBG : Already found the error. Please look at the code now.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I just have a small question. Why when I remove `break;` it doesn't sum the numbers? I'm just trying to understand, since I don't see the connection.

Comment: @DoombringerBG : Im using an image to explain, so lets continue in chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144137/discussion-between-user7185318-and-doombringerbg