# why count(*) does not work correctly?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this structure:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | user_pass |
+----+-----------+
| 1  |    01     |
| 2  |    10     |
+----+-----------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_pass = '$pass' limit 1
```

**The problem:**

```
$pass = '10';  // output: 1

$pass = '01';  // output: 0
```

while both values `10` and `01` are exist in the table, Why the output is different for each of them ?

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ec95/1) is a fiddle.

Comment: when you insert into the table 01 is cast to integer before writing to varchar.. put quotes around `'01'` and it works. [corrected fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e5fe/2)

Comment: @amdixon yes, you are right, thanks

Comment: @rekire: It's unfortunate that the actual bug wasn't mentioned in the question at all. This question is, ultimately broken and unsalvageable. Still, as currently written, it's a MySQL question. In general, questions tagged [tag:php],[tag:mysql] should be extremely rare, and right now I don't see a reason for this to be one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes are your friend. When you insert the rows you had no quotes this results that you input is interpreted as integer. So `01` gets `1` this explains why you get no results.

so your SQL should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (NULL, '01');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (NULL, '10');
```

Here as fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e5fe/1/0

The real issue (which can been found in the comments) is that PDO was used to insert the data into the database. The solution is to enfore to store the strings as string. For some reasons the values where automatically converted to integers, so the leading zero get lost.

The best way to enforce that the string will be a string is to cast it explicitly to string like this:

```
$password = (string)$_POST['password'];
```

Comment: thats fine, was a simple enough question

Comment: Thanks for answer, But I use PDO for inserting: `insert into table(password); execute(array($password));` So how should I use of quotes in my query ?

Comment: @Sajad how do you set the value to `$password`? I guess there is your bug.

Comment: like this: `$password = $_POST['password'];`

Comment: what did you do? combining the password with a empty string ? why really ? I think it is better: `$password = '. $_POST['password'].';`, of course I don't know it works or not ...

Comment: iIn your opinion is it better I use `''.` before all inputs ? `''.$name`, `''.$email` and ... ?

Comment: Regarding [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28098/995926) `password = (string)$_POST['password'];` would be the first choice.

Comment: @rekire very good !! thanks. +1 voteup for this point `(string)`. And is it better to I store all data as string ? like *name*, *email*, *cellphone* and ... or not ?