# multiple if and elseif statements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

in this case i have 69 category item and i wanted to store each of the item by the category.
so, my "IF and ELSEIF" statements will looks like this

```
    if ($category == 1){
       echo "1";
    } 
    elseif ($category == 2){
       echo "2";
    }
    elseif ($category == 3){
       echo "3";
    }
    elseif ($category == 4){
       echo "4";
    }
```

if i am keep with these way, this will takes lots of time. So is there any simple way to do this? Thank you

Comment: use `switch` maybe?

Comment: then i have to write until 69 case? its still the same right? @Sirko

Comment: What's the logic happening within the if/else if statements? Is it something that a database would be better suited for?

Comment: `echo category;` What are you really doing in the statements? You should add relevant code.

Comment: is `category` a constant or a variable?

Comment: Well, what exactly is the pattern? Given what you show, the most straight-forward implementation is `echo category`. But I'll assume your *actual* use case is a bit more complex than that, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for loop,

```
for($i=1;$i<70;$i++){
   if($category == $i){
      echo $i;
      break;
   } 
}
```

Comment: I think this is still wrong. It will end up in many if statements

Comment: Can be replaced by `echo $category` to do the same thing. Possibly `if ($category >= 1 && $category < 70) echo $category;`.

Answer (score 1):

use below way

```
$cat_arr = $result_arr_cat; // $result_arr_cat is result of category as associative
$arr_output = array('1'=>'1\'s output','2'=>'','3'=>''); // and so on
if(in_array($category,$cat_arr)){
 echo $category; // or keep the output in array of specific key echo $arr_output[$category];
}
```

Or even more simple

```
$arr_output = array(1=>'1\'s output', 2=>'', 3=>''); // and so on
if(array_key_exists($category, $arr_output)){
     echo $arr_output[$category];
}
```

Comment: You are defining `$arr_output` variable, but you are not using it

Comment: yhea i had added comment //or keep the output in array of specific key

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `in_array` and `range` functions:

```
if (in_array($category, range(1, 69))) {
    echo $category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just converting an integer to the equivalent string, use typecasting.

For example: `echo (string)$category;`

For more info, reference this answer: [ToString() equivalent in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/tostring-equivalent-in-php)