# Store query result as a string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have used `prepare`, `bind_param`, and `execute` statements to query my database and get only the first column. In php, how would I store the 1st returned value as a string?

In this example of returned values, I would want to store `value 1` as a string.

- `value 1`
- `value 2`
- `value 3`

Actual code:

```
  //connect to database

  $var1 = a;
  $var2 = b;
  $var3 = c;
  $var4 = d;
  $var5 = e;


  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM id_list WHERE variable1 = ? && variable2 = ? && variable3 = ? && variable4 = ? && variable5 = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);

  $stmt->execute();
  //How would I get the result here?
  $stmt->bind_result($result);
  echo $result;
```

Comment: where do you try to "store" the returned value from database? in a variable?  Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: ```reset($myDBResults);``` ?

Comment: @Dody I want to store it as a variable

Comment: It'd really help if you put in actual code that describes your problem rather than this vague overview of the situation.

Comment: Hint: Just like `bind_param`, which you're using properly, there's [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php). Another thing to note is it's traditionally `AND` in SQL, and MySQL's `&&` is highly non-standard.

Comment: @tadman So if I do `$stmt->bind_result($result);` and call `$result[0]`, it will give me the first returned value?

Comment: Read the documentation and associated examples more closely. It works a lot like `bind_param`, so if you're selecting just `id` then you will get a simple value back. It's not an array.

Comment: @tadman Based on the documentation, I called `$result`, but it's returning blank. What could be wrong? Thank you for helping me with what must seem like basic questions.

Comment: Edit your question with your attempt, that way the mistake will be more obvious.

Comment: The code is incomplete could you please show all the code? specially the part where you retrieve the result from the data base.

Comment: @Teocci I'm asking how to retrieve the result from the database. This is my full code.

Answer (score 1):

This code will complete your code and retrieve all the values that you need.

You can refer to the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/kr/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more info

Then you can replace the while with $result[0];

**NOTE:** don't forget to replace the values for the `database` connection. Your right values: `'my_user'`, `'my_password'` and `'my_database'`.

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_database');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM id_list 
            WHERE 
            variable1 = ? && 
            variable2 = ? && 
            variable3 = ? && 
            variable4 = ? && 
            variable5 = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);

    $var1 = a;
    $var2 = b;
    $var3 = c;
    $var4 = d;
    $var5 = e;

    /* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'Results:' . PHP_EOL;
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo $result . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $stmt->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can put some code example it could help.
Anyway I'm supposing that you're getting db results into an array.
So for example $myDBresults should be an array.
Then you can save it into a variable as a string [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/tostring-equivalent-in-php):

$myVar = (string)$myDBresults[0];  //cast to string first element.

Comment: Why is `(string)` necessary? Normally results are strings anyway.

Comment: Because I didn't know exactly if he needed to force casting for some reason.