# How to modify existing, unpushed commits in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How do I convert the value of a PHP variable to string?

I was looking for something better than concatenating with an empty string:

```
$myText = $myVar . '';
```

Like the ToString() method in Java or .NET.

Comment: so what is your question ? what is wrong with mentioned code ?

Comment: What is the relationship between the title and the body of your question ?

Comment: The content of the question is exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/tostring-equivalent-in-php ... A cut/paste error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ToString() equivalent in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/tostring-equivalent-in-php)